# Os problemas atuais, as descobertas e as iniciativas da sua comunidade

Tags: debate

Lembra como você começou a programar? Eu apostaria que quando muitos de vocês eram crianças, que brincavam com editores gráficos depois da escola, e, em algum momento, decidiram descobrir qual era a diferença entre os arquivos `.img` e `.exe`. Como resultado, você instalou o Turbo Pascal e, em vez de trabalhar com imagens engraçadas, tentou adicionar algo ao `"Hello World"` baixado. A abordagem de programação típica nesse estágio era assim: "Como aumentar um contador? - Copie o linha com o contador algumas vezes! Descobertas como funções ou um depurador não eram menos importantes que a Teoria da Relatividade.

Além disso, você se lembra quando fez mais progressos? Provavelmente, quando você conheceu um colega interessado em programar como você. É provável que durante o primeiro mês de trabalho em conjunto, o seu conhecimento tenha aumentado mais do que no ano anterior, quando você estudou sozinho a programação.

Parece que nossas comunidades internacionais estão crescendo e seguindo o mesmo cenário. Considere isto:

- Todas as comunidades internacionais começam com configurações padrão no site.
- Cada comunidade enfrenta problemas semelhantes que outras comunidades internacionais enfrentam em algum momento.
- Em algum momento, alguns dos problemas se tornam críticos.
- A comunidade, depois de contribuir com muito tempo e esforço, encontra soluções para os problemas críticos, um por um.
- Todas as outras comunidades internacionais não se beneficiam dessas soluções porque não sabem o que acontece em outros sites e ...
- ... eles continuam sofrendo, até que os mesmos problemas se tornam muito críticos em seus sites também.

Por que não trabalhar juntos?

## O problema

As comunidades internacionais enfrentam os mesmos problemas de novo e de novo, mas, isoladamente, eles não sabem que seus problemas foram frequentemente resolvidos em outros lugares.

### Dois exemplos

#### (1) Configurações do site

Em algum momento, no Stack Overflow em russo, recebemos muitas perguntas com saudações. Alguns usuários começaram a editar as perguntas, o que resultou em um grande número de edições na fila de revisão. Os revisores ficaram irritados com os editores e a comunidade começou a discutir o que fazer com essas edições, se era necessário editar questões antigas, etc. Começamos a cavar e descobrimos que no site há uma configuração que configura o mecanismo para remover saudações automaticamente quando uma questão é postada. Tipo da mesma história com o "obrigado" como comentários.

#### (2) Iniciativas

A empresa está constantemente melhorando o site, incluindo a interface do usuário. Às vezes isso leva a uma perda na tradução. A situação é muito chata e todas as comunidades internacionais sofreram com isso até o [g3rv4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238921/g3rv4?tab=profile) criar o [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/), o que ajuda a evitar a perda de traduções nos casos mais comuns. Infelizmente, traducir.win não é usado por todas as comunidades, o que resulta em algumas comunidades ainda perdendo traduções.

## Solução proposta

Eu acho que as comunidades internacionais podem ser mais eficazes se avançarmos juntas. O primeiro passo para o desenvolvimento conjunto é começar a compartilhar nossos problemas, descobertas e iniciativas com todas as comunidades internacionais.

### A essência da abordagem

No contexto "*Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites*", seria ótimo manter uma lista dos problemas atuais de cada comunidade, descobertas (também conhecidas como “problemas resolvidos”) e iniciativas sobre MSE.

Por exemplo, na seguinte forma:

#### Iniciativas

- *traducir.win*

  - Es: [Traduciendo el sitio… Esta vez, con más control sobre el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/10).
  - Ja: [サイトを翻訳するための新ツールの提案: Traducir](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2750/78).
  - Ru: [Мы переходим на Traducir.win для перевода интерфейса сайта!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8256/6)
  - Pt: [Estamos mudando para o Traducir.win para as traduções da interface](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7515/17539)
- Associações de perguntas

  - Ru: [Инструменты ассоциации вопросов между сайтами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6)
  - Es: [Preguntas con enlaces cruzados: identifiquemos las ya existentes en este sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1320/83) (a set of the most viewed questions in SO with a link to its related one in SOes; to do: link them somehow from SO to SOes for users with ES settings in their browser), [Herramientas de asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/10)
- Como tomar decisões baseadas no feedback da comunidade?

  - Es: [¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2093/65)
- Melhorando as traduções nos artigos da Central de Ajuda, fazendo pull-requests a um repositório.

  - Es: [Traduzcamos las páginas y enlaces del “Centro de Ayuda” y de “Privilegios”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3264/83). Articles with some flaws were community-wiki translated and then a pull request was done to a repo of a developer, so he pushed to the Stack Overflow en español site.
- O artigo no central da ajuda "Traduza do Inglês"

  - Es: [¿Debería traducir preguntas del inglés al español?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)
  - Ru: [Следует ли переводить сообщения с английского языка на русский?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)
  - Ja: [英語版サイトの質問や回答を、日本語に翻訳しても良いですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)
  - Pt: [Central de Ajuda: Posso traduzir conteúdo de outro site no SOpt? Como?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7678/17539)
- Compilado de dicas sobre como utilizar o site

  - Ru: [Подсказки о механиках работы Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7020/6)
  - Es: [Consejos sobre cómo usar el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3761/10)
- Banners da comunidade

  - Ru: [Поможем коллегам сделать первый шаг к профессиональному росту](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/6)
  - Ja: [オリジナルバナー作成について](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2915/78)
- Os valores da comunidade

  - Ja: [スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版で大切にしたい価値観とは](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2974/78)
  - Es: [Los valores fundamentales de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4031/10)
  - Ru: [Ключевые ценности сообщества Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8891/6)
  - Pt: [Os valores do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7742/5878)
- O que fazer com sites que contêm apenas conteúdo traduzido automaticamente do Stack Overflow em inglês

  - Ru: [Меньше спама, больше полезных знаний о программировании: как бороться с машинными переводами в поисковой выдаче](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8722/6)

#### Descobertas

- Removendo saudações automaticamente

  - [Should the word “hay” not be deleted at the beginning of posts, especially on Spanish SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304996)
  - [Let's make the automatic removal of salutations language specific!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305125)
  - Ru: [Автоматическое удаление приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6666/6)
- Excluir comentário automaticamente quando um usuário sinalizar como não é mais necessário

  - Ru: [Автоматическое удаление комментариев по тревоге «более не является необходимым»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/6).
- Advertências sobre perguntas e respostas

  - Es: [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/324)
- Ativando auditorias de revisão

  - Es: [Ya nos graduamos, habiliten los audits en las colas de revision](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2572/15301)
- Alterar o nome da medalha "Strunk & White" para algo mais específico localmente

  - Es: [Cambiemos el nombre de la medalla “Strunk & White” por algo más reconocible](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2077/83)
- Alerta antes de publicar uma pergunta em inglês

  - Es: [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83)
    <sub>based on [this answer by Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325866/1983854) to Meta SO's [*False Positive Spanish Language Detection when Asking Question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325865/1983854).</sub>
  - Ja: [英語で投稿されようとしている質問を、未然に誘導する仕組みが欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2838/19110)
  - Pt: [Que tal um alerta para perguntas em outro idiomas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7741/5878)
- Anúncios de promoções da comunidade

  - Es: [¿Podemos tener anuncios de promoción de la comunidad?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1140/83) --> [2017 edition](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/83)

#### Problemas atuais

- Adicionar validação para perguntas com apenas código

  - Es: [Añadamos una alerta en preguntas que son solo código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3491/a%c3%b1adamos-una-alerta-en-preguntas-que-son-solo-c%c3%b3digo)
  - Pt: [Que tal um alerta para perguntas com apenas código?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7735)
- Tendo a fila de revisão de triagem

  - Es: [Instauremos una cola de revisión “triaje” para que solo las preguntas con cierto nivel entren en la página de inicio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3200/83) (let's have the Triage review queue)
- Ter cartazes para universidades e centros de aprendizagem

  - Es: [Proposed by the CM](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1314/83), not clear how to get them.
- [CR] [A notification need to be sent when someone adds a new help center article or edits existing one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318782/289691).

---

Se você tem alguma ideia sobre a iniciativa, por favor, compartilhe!

Ao mesmo tempo, não hesite em adicionar os problemas, constatações e iniciativas atuais da sua comunidade à lista. Mesmo se mudarmos o processo com base no feedback, a lista nos ajudará a ver a situação real.

---

Traduzido de [Your community’s current problems, findings, and initiatives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317116/your-community-s-current-problems-findings-and-initiatives)

Comment: Viajou na maionese, não tinha nada disso na minha época :) Não tinha internet, não tinha escola, mal tinha computador, até em empresas, não se instalava nada, os livros eram ruins, complicado de importar qualquer coisa.

Comment: Discordo que as comunidades estão resolvendo seus problemas. Na verdade temos um único problema sério e esse não parece ter solução, a não ser que a ferramenta mude completamente, e esse problema é a chegada cada vez maior de usuário completamente sem condições sequer de se comunicar, sem conhecimento mínimo básico para programar ou até mesmo para fazer qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: O [fundador do Stack Overflow escreveu sobre isto](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/). Uma coisa que poucas pessoas entendem sobre o SO é que ele é uma wiki gatilhada pela necessidade de alguém. Nunca foi um fórum, nunca foi um local para ajuda pessoas com seus problemas específicos. A ferramenta não foi criada pensando nisto. Mas hoje o grosso das perguntas é neste sentido, há algumas pessoas que querem que isto seja assim, há outras que embarcam nisso por não entenderem o site, e ainda aqueles que só não ligam.

Comment: Mas há tb a própria SE que ñ entende, ou pelo menos faz de conta que não entende o que é o site e incentiva o uso como um fórum, mesmo sem que a ferramenta seja boa para isto. É um problema que fica complicado dar solução sem a SE querer, pq ou muda a ferramenta ou criará muitos problemas p/ quem chega no site agora. Além da pessoa ñ obter o q quer ela não sabe porque, ela não é bem instruída no que fazer, ela não é orientada paulatinamente para ser um usuário melhor, ela é até "protegida" de algum pequeno detalhe que pode gerar frustração, mas ao preço de ter várias outras grandes frustrações

Comment: O idioma sempre será uma barreira para os *colaboradores*, acho que o problema esta na *staff* e não na comunidade, boa vontade todos temos, mas como as coisas são não facilita, toma nossas energias e nos levam a repetir tentativas de corrigir as coisas quando em um cenário saudável umas poucas vezes seriam mais que suficiente para resolver definitivamente. Na teoria tudo é uma beleza, na realidade **não**.

Comment: Esses problemas referenciados aqui são na grande maioria problemas técnicos do site. Não são os problemas da comunidade. Como o problema que o @Maniero indicou, que tem a ver como a comunidade está interagindo com o site. Isso sim é o mais importante resolver.

Comment: @JorgeB. mas boa parte do problema da comunidade (letargia) tem a ver com o fato do mecanismo não consegue atender as demandas dos usuários e que a filosofia de qualidade já não existe mais e não acho que seja possível recuperá-la.

Comment: @Maniero sim, claro, o que eu quis dizer é que os problemas referenciados nesta pergunta são muito mais do cariz técnico de que problemas reais da comunidade. Claro que a solução dos problemas da comunidade podem ser resolvidos com alterações do mecanismo do site.