# Que tal um alerta para perguntas com apenas código?

Tags: novo-recurso

Perguntas criadas com apenas código tem sido um problema constante na nossa comunidade - mas não só na nossa, provavelmente em todas, tanto que o SOen já possui essa funcionalidade e no SOes estão implementando.

**Então que tal testarmos esta funcionalidade no SOpt?**

Se entendi corretamente, tal ferramenta não é ativada por padrão nas comunidades internacionais porque eles não garantem que possa funcionar com idiomas além do inglês. Uma [mensagem no Nicolas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47394733#47394733) no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal) comenta isso:

> I asked my coworkers. They say that the feature is not activated on any int'l sites. Basically that means we probably do not know if it works well with non English texts. If we activate the feature, we need to be carefully about new users and wait for their feedback. That might affect QPD. Please let me know if the community is ready and agrees with that.

Que em tradução livre seria:

> Perguntei aos meus colegas. Eles disseram que a ferramenta não está ativa nos sites internacionais. Basicamente, isso significa que provavelmente não sabemos se funciona bem com textos que não estejam em inglês. Se ativarmos o recurso, precisamos ter cuidado com novos usuários e aguardar o *feedback* deles. Isto pode afetar o QPD (que imagino ser quantidade de perguntas/dia). Por favor, avise-me se a comunidade tem interesse em testar.

O alerta apareceria ainda no formulário de criação da pergunta sugerindo que o usuário adicione mais informações do problema/código (e atenta ao fato que talvez o usuário formatou a pergunta inteira como código).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a comunidade aprovando, podemos solicitar que esta ferramenta seja ativada também no SOpt.

> [Existe o filtro também para respostas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49913193#49913193)

Comment: Acho excelente! Podiam fazer isso pra respostas também :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo principalmente para respostas :D

Comment: Bem interessante

Comment: Muito bom. às vezes me dá um nervoso perguntas: "O que está errado?" e na mensagem só o código. Outra coisa é colocar todo o log de erro na pergunta em vez de descrever um pouco o erro e colocar a mensagem de erro no texto.

Comment: O problema é ele saber que tem só código porque também é comum o cara nem dar o indent que marca como código. Dá pra fazer, mas se ele puder identificar que é código sem o indent ele podia aproveitar e indentar pra gente (ainda uw peça conformação como se fosse um user não confiável que fez edição.

Answer (score 4):

## Sim, acho que vale a pena testar

Eu sou a favor de ativar esta ferramenta no SOpt. Vejo que é bastante comum publicações que possuem somente código, tanto como perguntas quanto respostas e ambas não são úteis desta forma para a comunidade. Elas quase sempre, se não sempre, são acompanhadas de vários votos negativos e comentários do tipo "você poderia explicar melhor?". Isso não é só prejudicial para o próprio autor como para a comunidade, pois acaba inserindo ruído com conteúdo que dificilmente será aproveitado por alguém.

Aliado a isso, não vejo como esta notificação possa trazer algum malefício para a comunidade. Se a pessoa publicar apenas código, ela será notificada para acrescentar textos explicando o contexto; se ela apenas formatou de forma errada a publicação, terá também na notificação para a pessoa averiguar se não é problema na formatação. Em ambos os casos a publicação final tenderá a ser melhor que a inicial e vejo isso como um ponto positivo.

Vai acontecer da pessoa inserir qualquer texto apenas para não exibir mais a mensagem? Provavelmente, mas não é objetivo desta ferramenta bloquear isso.