# Se você pudesse alterar QUALQUER coisa no site, o que mudaria?

Tags: debate

É visto no meta que estamos passando por tempos turbulentos e isso não é de hoje. Sugestões aparecem em diversos canais de comunicação, na grande maioria são discutidos e muitas ficam perdidas no tempo sem alguma ação específica, seja porque a comunidade não age ativamente, seja porque simplesmente não temos ferramentas disponíveis para agir, seja porque a SE é omissa ou por qualquer motivo.

Mas se você tivesse liberdade de alterar QUALQUER coisa na comunidade, o que você alteraria?

Por que você faria essa alteração? Você vê isso como um problema atual na comunidade? Se sim, como julga que isso afeta negativamente? Se é uma melhoria, como julga que a comunidade seria melhor após a alteração?

Busque limitar uma resposta por cada alteração que você faria, caso sejam múltiplas.

A ideia do debate é justamente levantar o máximo de alterações que a própria comunidade faria, levantar quais teriam os maiores impactos e verificar a viabilidade de cada uma. Por isso, tente fundamentar o melhor possível a sua alteração e evite coisas do tipo "mudaria ... porque não acho que funciona". Sempre justifique, se possível, com dados reais.

Antes de responder, veja se a mesma alteração já foi proposta por outro usuário:

<sup>As descrições abaixo são sínteses grosseiras daquilo que foi sugerido na resposta. Para mais detalhes, acesse a resposta.</sup>

- [Mecanismo semi-automatizado que orienta os usuários como o site funciona](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8144/5878)
- [Voltar os usuários que eram muito ativos, que produziam qualidade em tudo, não só respostas.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8145/5878)
- [Focar mais no foco inicial do site, de ter respostas canônicas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8146/5878)
- [Modal informativo sobre respostas para usuários inexperientes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8148/5878)
- [Alerta fixado na página para o autor da pergunta fechada informado que fechamento pode ser revertido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8149/5878)
- [Não divulgar o nome de quem votou para fechar a pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8150/5878)
- [Adicionar tags da pergunta quando compartilhar em redes sociais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8151/5878)
- [Validação no Snippet sobre a linguagem utilizada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8152/5878)
- [Definir meio de avaliação do comportamento de usuários nas filas de análise](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8153/5878)
- [Emojis para representar o sentimento da comunidade perante a pergunta sem afetar a reputação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8154/5878)
- [Resposta aceita deixar de ser fixada no topo da lista mesmo que não seja a melhor votada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8155/5878)
- [Permitir votos de fechamento mesmo depois da pergunta estar fechada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8156/5878)
- [Permitir que a comunidade vote para transformar uma resposta em comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8157/5878)
- [Opção de converter uma resposta em uma nova pergunta (mesmo que fechada)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8158/5878)
- [Aumentar os privilégios de usuários com medalha de ouro em uma tag](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8159/5878)
- [Notificação ao usuário quando há algo errado na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8160/5878)
- [Significado dos votos no Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8161/5878)
- [Perguntas devem iniciar fechadas e a votação para abrí-las](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8162/5878)
- [Mais privilégios para os moderadores atuarem na comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8163/5878)
- [Lista de comentários para justificar anonimamente um voto negativo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8164/5878)
- [Comentários automáticos (anónimos ou não) para justificar votos de fechamento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8165/5878)
- [Incentivar mais a participação do usuário na comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8167/5878)
- [Mais medalhas que recompensem votos em outras respostas (paralelas a sua)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8168/5878)
- [Não remover votos legais para outros usuários quando uma conta é removida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8170/5878)
- [Opção de notificar um usuário para tentar responder a pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8172/5878)
- [Distinguir por motivo os votos dados no fechamento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8173/5878)
- [Opção de ignorar usuário no site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8174/5878)
- [Voltar a ter contadores nas filas de análise](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8175/5878)
- [Outras formas de contribuir com conteúdo de qualidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8176/5878)
- [Gerente de comunidade nativo em português e exclusivo para o SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8177/5878)
- [Sinalizar que um comentário deveria ser uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8178/5878)
- [Seguir atividade de outros usuários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8179/5878)
- [Quiz do funcionamento do site ao criar a primeira pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8180/5878)
- [Opção de criar os próprios comentários enlatados](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8181/5878)
- [Perguntas antigas voltando à página inicial](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8183/5878)
- [Ter o StackOverflow Jobs em português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8184/5878)
- [Aumentar a quantidade de votos diários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8185/5878)
- [Notificação na caixa de entrada de votos no Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8186/5878)
- [Estabelecer um tempo de mandato para os moderadores](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8187/5878)
- [Votos positivos em perguntas voltar a valer 5 pontos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8188/5878)
- [Notificação de edição, remoção e reabertura de perguntas que o usuário votou](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8189/5878)
- [Criar uma sala com o "assunto da semana" no chat](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8193/4492)
- [Adequar critérios de algumas medalhas de acordo com o tamanho do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8202/112052)

Comment: Sem tempo pra elaborar, mas resumindo, isso: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803

Comment: @hkotsubo que é basicamente minha primeira resposta aqui. Eu não vou elaborar porque sabemos que é só trivia, nada vai mudar :( :)

Comment: Eu entendo que a comunidade tem muitos problemas com qualidade e afins e talvez o foco da pergunta seja este, mas existem muitos problemas e demanda de orientar, e talvez forçar as ferramentas do site a auto-orientar como usar, emitindo modais (alertas) com uma certa orientação para pessoas com score inferior já resolveria uns 10% de problema de gasto de tempo com coisas "bobas" e assim focariamos em problemas de verdade que a comunidade apresenta, por isso das minhas duas sugestões sobre os modais de confirmação.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Uma outra ideia seria fazer isso baseado em medalhas ao invés de reputação. Por exemplo, fazer uma ação se o usuário ainda não possui uma determinada medalha (ou a última vez que recebeu foi a mais de 1 anos atrás), mas para isso teria que criar dezenas de novas, o que provavelmente seria inviável. Abrir um modal sobre o Tour para sempre que o usuário publicar algo enquanto não possuir a medalha "informado", por exemplo.

Comment: @Woss as regras sobre score ou medalha eu deixo livre para a comunidade e usuários experimentes mediarem e decidirem, mas o que importa é a ideia de orientar através de "uma barreira", que pode ser ignorada, mas ainda sim toda vez estará lá.

Comment: Não vou dizer que sou a melhor pessoa com UX, mas acredite, trabalhei com mais de 40 usuários, um pior que o outro, tirando que durante 5 anos trabalhando, tivemos demissões e novas contratações, então não sei afirmar com quantos usuários eu tive que orientar e melhorar a UX por problema que enfrentei, mas certas ações minhas no visual ajudaram a evitar de ficar orientando, muitas coisas eram nas barreiras, outras foram criando steps, mas nunca foi receita de bolo, cada caso era testado e refeito várias vezes.

Comment: Eu tenho ideias de monte do que poderia mudar, mas seria algo tão diferente que não seriam mudanças, é fechar este site e começar outro.

Comment: Hoje em dia, eu mudaria os donos :P

Comment: @bfavaretto e dependendo de quem for (pois se essa baderna toda já for uma "preparação de terreno" para atender um futuro dono, nao vai resolver nada)

Comment: @bfavaretto eu entendi o que disse, mas os donos não são o problema direto, ainda que sempre são eles que podem mudar o rumo indiretamente.

Comment: Com o tanto de perguntas fechadas, voltar os usuários que eram muito ativos não adiantaria muito. Acho que o site precisa, inicialmente, melhorar o sistema de perguntas. Atualmente há muitas perguntas que por falta de atenção (ou conhecimento) do autor, que posta apenas uma imagem ou apenas código. Ademais, seria legal um sistema de [Notificação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Utilizar_API_Notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es#Cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_uma_notifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: Melhorar no só no principal ou no meta também?

Comment: @Costamilam Entenda site como SOpt em todas as suas frentes.

Comment: Com os últimos acontecimentos com a SE Inc, isto aqui virou uma brincadeira, divertida, mas não mais que isso. Não quer dizer que nada será feito, mas nenhuma mudança expressiva será feita. Eles estão cortando custos e mudando o foco, e nós não importamos mais.

Comment: Não sei se todos notaram, mas ontem eles fizeram [uma "grande" mudança](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/401803) que foi sugerida em **2012**. O que aliás, está na média, pois [esse aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/401803) por exemplo demorou 7 anos pra ser atendido. Então quem sabe eles atendam algum dos pedidos abaixo por volta de 2028 (se ainda existir alguma comunidade).

Comment: @hkotsubo detalhe que muitos podem não ter percebido, a melhoria foi colocar o ícone ali, o resto já existia.

Comment: @hkotsubo, Nessa velocidade, "Asked 7 years, 10 months ago", pode ter certeza que quando alguma mudança vier os autores de algumas das sugestões não estarão vivos para ver a requisição atendida.

Comment: Como tudo o que estou vendo, no meta, no tweeter, e outras fontes sobre a SE, pode esquecer essas coisas, é quase oficial, somos gado.

Comment: Limitar quantas vezes um moderador pode fechar perguntas num dia.

Comment: @Diogo seria melhor a comunidade entender o que é on e o que é off e qual o minimo de qualidade para algo ser razoavel, assim moderadores não precisariam se preocupar com isto ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim você está certo nesse ponto, vejo muita pergunta de baixa qualidade e não vejo comentários pedindo o usuário para melhorar. A pergunta é fechada de uma vez.

Comment: @Diogo se você acha isso deve colocar como resposta, assim as pessoas podem votar a favor ou contra. Quando coloca só como comentário não dá para fazer isso e é só uma vontade pessoal momentânea, não contribui para a comunidade evoluir. Eu já tentei fazer você entender os problemas reais sobre o que acontece nessa comunidade, passei *links* para saber como é a vida real e deixar de fazer especulações, mas não adiantou muito. Reclamar não adianta nada, fazer algo adianta, comece fazer, novamente os *links* foram passados em outro post pra aprender fazer isso, se não teve interesse em ler ...

Comment: @Maniero OK, cada um faz o que pode.

Comment: @Diogo como eu lhe disse ontem, quando eu cheguei no site tive logo de cara 3 perguntas fechadas, mas ao invés de culpar os outros eu procurei tentar entender aonde eu tinha falhado, se as pessoas esperarem que os outros fiquem as carregando não é um caminho para a independência, como eu disse, as pessoas precisam aprender *"ajudar os outros a lhe ajudarem"*, ou seja eu procurei por mim mesmo ver aonde estavam os erros de minhas perguntas, e principalmente olhei como os outros perguntavam, não só a maneira de escrever, mas de transmitir o problema e desde então sempre consegui respostas. ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que estamos falando de coisas distintas, eu não tive nenhuma pergunta fechada, estou reclamando (o que posso fazer, pois o site é aberto e faço parte dele) da quantidade grande de perguntas fechadas (dentro do escopo) sem nem um comentário. Se isso incomoda alguém (o fato de eu questionar isso), já não é problema meu. Vi sua pergunta https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8192/a-stack-overflow-e-cms-sabem-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-helpdesk-para-as-demais-perguntas e ela é perfeita, estou percebendo exatamente isso e acho que a galera está fechando por isso.

Comment: @Diogo então estamos falando do mesmo, eu não me refiro a ti, eu me refiro a qualquer um que venha participar do site, eu não acho que devamos ser babás, acho que cada individuo deve ser independente e aprender a *"ajudar os outros a ajuda-lo"*, se pode aprender vendo exemplos pode aprender a perguntar vendo outras perguntas que foram aceitas, assim evitando que suas perguntas futuras sejam fechadas ou até editar suas perguntas atuais fechadas para que sejam reabertas, o fechamento não é pra sempre, basta a pessoa ser pró-ativa a favor de si mesma [...]

Comment: [...] eu usei a mim mesmo de exemplo, corri atrás pra aprender como perguntar olhando perguntas ruins e boas para entender aonde errava e aprendi por mim mesmo como pedir ajuda, na minha época era pior, pq não tinha dicas, agora o META está repleto de dicas, de como "sobreviver" no site, textos fáceis, eu aprendi sozinho, então demorei um pouco, mas se tivesse os links que o pessoal elaborou eu teria conseguido mais rápido ainda. Hoje é só o pessoal ler os links e ser um pouco pró-ativo que conseguem por si só notarem como melhorar suas proprias postagens, não precisamos de "babás" ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, tem horas que não da mesmo, a galera trata como fórum, dos dois lados.

Answer (score 26):

O facebook tem isso:

[image]

O GitHub tem isso:

[image]

Penso que nós poderíamos ter botões com ícones deste tipo específicos para sinalizar o que as pessoas acham da pergunta, mas sem influenciar a reputação ou o fechamento (ao menos de forma direta). O número de cliques em cada ícone é visualizável pelo autor da pergunta, mas não os nomes de quem clicou. Exemplos:

- [image] - Eu acho que você precisa melhorar a sua pergunta.
- [image] - Sua pergunta é confusa e não consigo entender o que é que você está perguntando.
- [image] - Sua pergunta parece estar incompleta.
- [image] - Acho que sua pergunta tem problemas de conteúdo.
- [image] - Não vou dar +1, mas também não vou dar -1.

Comment: É útil sim, o voto é algo muito mais sério, precisa algo pra agradar as pessoas e indicar algo que não mexa na reputação. Claro que pode dar errado e as pessoas começarem usar isto e não o voto. Mas aí caímos também no problema de não termos mais uma comunidade ativa e nada que seja feito mudará isto. EU não quis entrar em detalhes achar que essas coisas não acontecem, mas está dentro do que eu respondi que deveria ter melhores formas de indicar ao usuário oque está acontecendo, algo  mais autómático e menos pessoal.

Comment: A pessoa q votou continuaria "oculta"? Sei que é um sistema a parte, que até ajudaria no interesse de informar, mas queria saber se isto exibiria quem "votou", não que faça diferença, mas o site nos ultimos tempos tem tanta pergunta ruim e tem ocorrido muitas discussões por parte de teimosos em entenderem o problema

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não mostraria quem votou. Mas quem quiser se revelar, é mais que convidado a deixar um comentário.

Comment: eu li mal a postagem, vc escreveu logo abaixo que era "privado", desculpe :P ... +1

Comment: Podia ser só ASCII emojis: (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: Nem nunca tinha pensado nisto, mas acho esta ideia muito boa, e especialmente para quem vem de outras plataformas acabaria por surgir com naturalidade. No fim acho que iria criar mais interesse por participar e utilizar o site no geral.

Comment: Já tem algo inicial no Teams, nã oé algo que teriam muito trabalho.

Comment: Agora no SOen tem os "reactions", você pode agradecer algum post ou resposta. [Mais informações](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reactions)

Comment: @danieltakeshi É. Mas dentre tantas boas opções de reações possíveis que poderiam implementar, escolheram uma que não faz sentido porque o botão de upvote já sinaliza isso.

Comment: Foi o que eu pensei na hora, somente agradecimento de reação. Nenhuma utilidade nova...

Comment: No Teams essa funcionalidade está disponível. https://imgur.com/a/8Ar0SO8

Answer (score 19):

Deve permitir que a comunidade vote para transformar uma resposta em comentário. Não faz sentido ela poder fazer a remoção da resposta e não transformar em comentário.

Muito do trabalho dos moderadores é realizar isto.

Seria interessante poder colocar o motivo que a pessoa sinalizou para outras pessoas entenderem isso.

A calibragem tem que ser pensada.

Answer (score 16):

Vou repetir algo que eu já disse em outros contextos. Eu removeria o "pin" da resposta aceita pelo autor da pergunta. Aceitação não mais mudaria a ordem das respostas, só deixaria o V verdinho do lado da escolhida.

Penso que as respostas podem continuar sendo ordenadas por votos (por padrão), tempo, e até outras características, mas que o V verdinho não interfira na ordem dos resultados.

É extremamente danoso o funcionamento atual, pois por mais sem noção que a resposta seja, atrai votos e fica em destaque, e a comunidade só tem a alternativa de se conformar com isso.

Tirando essa ordem artificial, as respostas mais votadas por padrão ficariam sempre no topo. Por uma questão de UX e UI, pode-se simplesmente mostrar uma frase discreta abaixo da pergunta (somente quando a do topo não for a aceita) dizendo "clique aqui para ver a resposta escolhida pelo autor" - razoavelmente discreto, que simplesmente rolasse para a âncora desejada.

Comment: Está em curso uma discussão mais séria para fazer isto, não sei como está o andamento.

Comment: Somando a isto, acho que talvez algo como um badge abaixo do score **"melhor resposta"**, mas não seria baseado no score, e também haveria um **"resposta não indicada"** (ou outro nome), não sei o que sugerir para essas "medalhas" nas respostas como avaliador, acho que talvez a pessoa ser "medalha de ouro" em uma das tags ajudaria.

Comment: Eu já tinha ouvido essa sua sugestão há bastante tempo atrás e acho que era uma das mais simples de implementar e com efeitos bastante positivos no site. Mas parece que a SE não tá nem ai.

Answer (score 16):

Deve permitir que votos de fechamento sejam dados mesmo depois que o fechamento seja efetivado para indicar para a comunidade que há apoio depois da ação concluída.

Isto é importante mais agora por que moderadores estão sendo responsáveis por muitos fechamentos (não só no SOpt), e porque pode ser que mude o mínimo de votos para fechar totalmente pela comunidade. É especialmente necessário para um moderador votar mesmo depois que outro já votou para deixar mais claro que o fechamento não foi tão monocrático assim, mesmo que a decisão teve uma ação vinculante imediata.

Comment: Ou seja, quanto mais votos de fechamento, mais de reabertura seria necessário, evitando reabertura fácil de coisa extremamente problemática.

Comment: Sim, esse ponto é complementar. Pegando carona em outro ponto postado aqui, talvez ter peso maior para quem tem certa medalha ou pontuação.

Answer (score 16):

**Os privilégios para quem possui medalha de ouro em uma tag poderiam ser maiores do que apenas gerenciar duplicatas.**

Um usuário que possui a medalha de ouro em uma tag possui conhecimentos mais que suficientes para determinar se uma pergunta é erro de digitação, se está insuficientemente clara, etc. Não faz sentido este usuário poder decidir por conta se a pergunta é duplicata mas não poder decidir que é erro de digitação.

A autonomia destes usuários **dentro da tag** poderia ser maior podendo fechar com qualquer motivo sem enviar a pergunta para a fila. Isso já ajudaria a desafogar muitos dos gargalos do site e reduziria bastante as filas de análise, que geralmente estão entupidas de coisas e muitos usuários acabam analisando sem muito critério.

Comment: Que é uma variação da [redução de votos necessários para fechar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8132/101). Eu acho que muito privilégio deve ser dado para a comunidade (que hoje só moderador tem), mas alguns devem ser tirados de todos e dar só para quem mostra merecimento. A dosagem a ser discutida. Isto é quase outra proposta, né? :)

Comment: Eu pessoalmente sempre achei que os privilégios de ouro numa tag eram reduzidos, mas agora confirmo que não era o único :D

Answer (score 14):

Criaria um mecanismo semiautomatizado que fosse informando o usuário como o site funciona e como resolver seus problemas. Talvez envolvendo alguma forma de IA em algumas partes. A lista de mecanismos específicos é enorme do que pode ajudar. Sempre dando alguma margem para interferência humana, por isso não deveria ser 100% automatizada. O mais importante é ter ações padrões e boas indicações.

Pra mim o grande problema é os usuários terem que lidar com tudo manualmente, junto com os novatos não entenderem o site. Precisava de algo que vá informando como o site é gradativamente. Quase tudo que a pessoa reclama já foi tratado antes. Precisa facilitar pros usuários ativos ajudarem os novatos se adequarem ao site, de forma simples e precisa. Assim reduz o trabalho e a impedância natural que ocorre pelo tratamento mais pessoal.

Isto inclui restrição maior ao usuário que não quer, ou não consegue (analfabeto funcional) seguir as instruções. Tudo tem limite. O que não dá para fazer é lidar com pessoas que não conseguem nem ler e interpretar as mensagens que são postas até pelo sistema. A pessoa reclama de algo que não está acontecendo com a pergunta dela.

Jájá o site fará 15 anos, a computação mudou muito de lá pra cá, hoje este site é ultrapassado.

Ajudaria se os motivos de fechamento tivessem uma aprofundamento e poder escolher um motivo mais específico que o usuário seria notificado. Eu acho que as novas mensagens deixaram tudo muito vago, acho que precisa ser mais detalhado e específico possível. E é loucura acha que todo mundo ficará criando comentários personalizados para cada caso na proporção que temos hoje de muitas perguntas ruins e poucos usuários ativos.

Outro mecanismo que já ajudaria muito até porque acontece com frequência quase inacreditável (e diz muito do comprometimento que a pessoa está quando digita a pergunta): [Que tal um alerta para perguntas em outro idiomas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7741/101).

Um exemplo de caso que nem precisa de IA: [Sistema orientar "automaticamente" usuários em perguntas duplicatas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6099/101).

Entre as informações que podem ser dadas para a pessoa é indicar um IDE online para ele postar o código de forma que já possa ser verificado, o que pode fazer com que a pessoa ache o erro sozinha. O sistema precisa ser mais assertivo para ajudar a pessoa resolver seu problema sozinho ou então fazer uma pergunta melhor. Relacionado: [Por que não integrar o SOPT com o Ideone (ou outra ferramenta do tipo)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5756/101).

Outra que ajudaria: [Que tal um alerta para perguntas com apenas código?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7735/101).

Answer (score 14):

Quando uma pergunta fosse fechada ao invés de ficar no topo dela o motivo do fechamento, apenas para o autor da pergunta, deveria ficar um div fixo (`position:fixed`) em amarelo ou laranja com os dizeres:

> ```
> Sua pergunta pode ser reaberta, fechamento não é o mesmo que remoção,
> siga as dicas [aqui](link) para que você corrija os problemas dela
> ```

Porque acredito que as pessoas não tem noção o suficiente que elas tem que melhorar as próprias postagens e por mais que a SE se esforce no UI e UX do site, nem sempre atingem o resultado desejado para entendimento.

Comment: É uma especialização do que eu postei. tem uma série de pontos de UX que precisam melhorar, e é incrível que eles contrataram uma pessoa de UX e nada melhora. È quase inacreditável que depois de tanto tempo você não vê melhorias reais de UX, coisas simples e grande impacto. E a pessoa nem precisa ser criativa, basta olhar o que estão falando que está ruim e fazer. Especialista em UX tá virando *coach*.

Comment: @Maniero concordo, a propria comunidade dá sugestões no Metão, mas eles estranhamente se focam nas "superficiais", como aquele sistema de aba com ordenação, é útil, mas na pratica não resolveu nenhum problema real, só é um facilitador, outra coisa foi a mudança do StackMenu, agora alguns links ficam na barra a esquerda da tela, mas isso também nem de longe era um problema na forma anterior, e não resolveu nada critico.

Answer (score 14):

Um dos recursos mais pedidos é a notificação quando há algo errado com a pergunta, principalmente quando recebe um negativo.

A filosofia do sistema sempre foi não importunar o usuário com isto, mas vai contra a ideia que o usuário precisa melhorar o conteúdo, ter uma experiência real mais adequada e sem melhor recebido.

Jogar a sujeita embaixo do tapete não resolve problema alguma, apenas faz todos ficarem infelizes de um jeito ou de outro. É bobo querer fazer de conta de o negativo não ocorreu.

Deve notificar e dar dicas para a pessoa não ficar nervosa com aquilo e o que pode fazer para reverter a situação. Isto é produtivo.

Isto foi discutido em [Notificação de votos negativos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4863/101) (note que não foi recusado, até hoje está em revisão). No metão tem várias discussões do tipo.

Outro é notificar o fechamento, isto [já foi discutido no metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/140010).

Answer (score 13):

Diante das perguntas e respostas de má qualidade, que [incomoda várias pessoas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8142/voc%C3%AA-est%C3%A1-feliz-no-sopt), e diante do fato que as pessoas dificilmente vão ler grandes textos antes de  utilizar um site que contém regras mais rígidas de qualidade, sugiro o seguinte:

- Ao criar sua **primeira pergunta no site**, o usuário deverá ler obrigatoriamente a versão [curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-sopt-vers%C3%A3o-curta) (ou [longa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs)) do manual de sobrevivência e responder algumas perguntas sobre ele. Ele precisa acertar algumas respostas para poder fazer sua primeira pergunta no site.

Imagino algo do tipo "assinale a resposta correta":

1. O SO é um fórum¹?

   1. Sim
   2. Não

      ¹. Um fórum é um espaço...
2. Qual título de pergunta abaixo traz mais informações do problema?

   1. Socorro!
   2. Me ajude com Java
   3. Problema no Java
   4. Erro de compilação ao chamar um método a partir de um método estático no Java

Entre muitas outras.

Não acho que seja necessário fazer o mesmo para a primeira resposta, mas deixo a critério dos demais achar que é tão ou mais necessário. Acho muito difícil que algo assim seja colocado em prática por conta da política atual da empresa e isto, é claro, deveria passar por uma experimentação (teste A/B) antes de ser implantada no site todo.

Comment: É dessas que duvido que seja feito, mas é importantíssimo. De fato as respostas são bem menos problemáticas, e podemos lidar com isso, o que não está dando são as perguntas muito ruins.

Comment: Eu adoro a idéia do cara ter que se identificar, pq quem dá as caras acaba tomando mais cuidado com o que posta, e adoro a idéia de ter que fazer algum tipo de comprovação periódica de que é minimamente alfabetizado.

Answer (score 13):

Permitir mais votos diários, principalmente em perguntas, para usuários com alta reputação. Poderia ser 1 voto extra por cada 10K que a pessoa tenha.

Pode ser bloqueado para quem tem advertência ou suspensão por fraude ou perseguição. Poderia pensar em até retirar votos quem tem este tipo de problema.

Um dos problemas atuais é que poucas pessoas votam e algumas poderiam votar mais. Usuários de alta reputação são mais confiáveis para dar votos com mais critério.

Comment: Eu quero dar um voto na sua resposta e não posso: "Limite de votos diários atingido. Vote novamente em 3 horas."

Answer (score 13):

Notificar a quem votou (tanto up quanto down) uma postagem no próprio stack-exchange-button (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-button) junto com outra notificações quando ocorrer mudanças como:

- Edição da postagem
- Remoção da postagem
- Reabertura da postagem

Entre outras que talvez sejam necessárias (agora não consigo pensar em mais nada, depois edito), no entanto junto com isto também deveria haver:

- "Silenciar postagem"

No caso de downvotes você assinaria automaticamente a postagem e optaria por silenciar (não assinar)

No caso de upvote você só assinaria se desejasse

Lembrando que poderia assinar mais de uma resposta em uma mesma pergunta, mas no caso de assinar perguntas após o voto você também seria notificado de novas respostas, pois já vi "respostas" salvarem perguntas ruins.

Comment: Eu acho que é uma especialização ou dup de: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8160/101, ela está detalhando mais, mas é boa. Tenho a impressão que alguns casos a proposta deveria ser melhorada. Quem sabe até tudo ser wiki, assim tb ñ tem voto na pessoa.

Comment: @Maniero se concordar mesclamos, ai poderia colocar um "titulo" dizendo, uma "sugestão de como poderia funcionar, mas pode haver outras maneiras, comente"

Answer (score 11):

Perguntas fechadas **não** deveriam conter o nome de quem fechou, nem mesmo para o autor da pergunta ou das respostas, quem poderia ver seriam:

- Apenas os demais que votaram para fechar
- Moderadores (o que é óbvio)
- Usuário com acesso as ["ferramentas de moderação"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (que requer 10.000 de score).

  > Talvez 10k seja pouco poderia ser até o ["usuário confiável"](http://(ou%20outro%20n%C3%ADvel%20%22maior%22,%20como%20https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)) (requer 20k)

Sugiro isto porque os problemas de perguntas fechadas são sempre nas próprias perguntas, mas quando alguém vota para fechar, geralmente o autor da pergunta pensa que aquilo é parcial e de propósito e não se esforça em entender que é ele quem deve melhorar a pergunta, então ao invés de se focar em resolver o problema de qualidade da pergunta a pessoa gasta energia discutindo com quem fechou. Note que essa sugestão irá funcionar melhor se combinada com esta:

- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8149/3635

Porque o que mais falta é a pessoa entender que o problema da qualidade da pergunta é ela quem tem que resolver e que pergunta fechada não é o mesmo que pergunta deletada, pois se ajustada a maioria poderia ser reaberta

Comment: Não sei se tanto, mas a ideia é boa. Talvez não mostrar inicialmente porque a pessoa tá com raiva na hora. Acho que isto é útil para evitar brigas, não outros motivos. Acredito que mais pessoas votariam para fechar se tivesse isso. Eu até acho que filosoficamente tudo deveria ser mostrado, mas entende is problemas que isto causa, ainda que a transparência deveria gerar menos problemas... no mundo ideal.

Comment: Essa só resultaria se voltasse a aparecer passado um prazo.

Comment: Eu só mudaria que, a partir de um certo score, não moderadores também pudessem ver, assim, se alguém discorda ou o autor de score alto, pode falar/pedir orientação com os fechadores

Comment: @Costamilam concordo com isto, apesar que acho que só deveria ser visivel quando liberasse "ferramentas de 'moderador'" (10.000: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), assim visualizar seria como ser um "moderador honorário"

Comment: @JorgeB. o que acha do edit?

Comment: Também não é mal pensado. Acho que ficou bom.

Answer (score 11):

Talvez seja tarde demais, mas deveria ter uma medalha para incentivar votos em respostas, mesmo que concorrentes suas. Já existe, mas pode ter mais e [já foi proposto no metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116735/140010). Deve ampla aceitação (até de funcionário), é fácil implementar e nada foi feito, nem mesmo um argumento contra foi postado pela SE.

Mais medalhas seria legal, é divertido, ainda que alguns casos as pessoas abusem o sistema para consegui-las. Deveria cria novas todos os anos.

Answer (score 11):

**CM, nativo no idioma português, exclusivo para o site SOpt**

Ter apenas um responsável por todas as comunidades internacionais é querer que o mesmo faça nada e fique sempre sobrecarregado de demandas. Ter um responsável que nem chega perto de falar o idioma da comunidade internacional piora tudo. A comunicação é completamente limitada, só existem barreiras e naturalmente faz com que ele seja omisso em todas as questões no site.

Ter um CM que fale português, exclusivo para o SOpt, é o mínimo para se começar a construir a "ponte de comunicação" entre a comunidade e a empresa que tanto eles pedem.

Comment: Isso é algo que tínhamos e perdemos, e hoje eu sinto muita falta, muita falta mesmo.

Comment: Estou em cima do muro nessa :) Tem desvantagens também. Claro que depende da pessoa que vai ser, mas hoje parece que os funcionários tem um perfil muito parecido (nada de diversidade real e não seria bom). Ter um CM que fale português de forma oficial e claramente este CM esteja à disposição para ajudar a comunidade eu acho bom, mas se for para ele impor suas vontades para a comunidade sem participar dele, ou seja, mandar os outros fazer o que ele deseja sem se responsabilizar, isso eu não acho bom.

Comment: @Maniero Dos 8 CMs restantes atualmente (há 3 dias atrás eram 10). 2 deles falam português, sendo um do Brasil (Cesar M) e um de Portugal (JNat). Já vi o JNat por aqui no SOpt em raras ocasiões, mas nunca vi o Cesar M nesta comunidade. Considerando que o número de CMs para todas as centenas de comunidades atuais é tão pequeno assim e ainda está diminuindo, provavelmente querer um CM exclusivo deve ser pedir demais. E é claro que o clima político na SE é extremamente desfavorável.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim, não tem como por um exclusivo, só alguém que tenha um pouco mais de disponibilidade pra atender as demandas daqui. O Cesar já fez algo de tradução, mas essencialmente não interagiu c/ o povo, foi bem mecânico. Não que seja de todo ruim assim :)

Comment: Não votei, mas definitivamente não acho que isso (dedicado) seja problema. Apesar de eu me simpatizar muito com o CM que tivemos (como indivíduo, não como CM), tendo ele como CM dedicado acho que não era um diferencial extremo do site. Tinha hora que até atrapalhava por "conflito de comando" - as regras escritas do site não batiam com as regras informais e eu nunca soube o que era opinião do CM ou o que era da empresa. Ok, foi muito pontual (um só) para poder avaliar. E no fim ele só trouxe uma prévia da esquisitice que isso aqui está na visão da empresa, talvez pra ele tb tenha sido dificil.

Comment: Se um dos CMs que falam português traduzissem para o Nicolas **antes** dele postar aqui, já seria um progresso, mas até disso eu já desisti. Troquei vários emails com ele sobre isso e ele insiste que é melhor assim do que ter um CM dedicado ao site. Ironicamente ele é o único que posta aqui...

Answer (score 10):

Quando mais cedo o AP tomar consciência de que a sua pergunta tem problemas mais cedo poderá corrigir.
Muitos não entendem o que significa o voto negativo.

Deveria ser disponibilizado, na altura de voto negativo, um conjunto de comentários que o votante escolheria para "justificar" o seu voto. Esses comentários seriam anónimos.

A intenção dos comentários é a de informar ao AP os possíveis problemas da pergunta.

Comment: Hoje, se você for ver as perguntas recentes, elas praticamente entram com um voto negativo. Minha sensação é que tem alguém de sacanagem que dá downvote em todas as perguntas e respostas. Até perguntas respondidas e respostas aceitas parecem receber downvote sem nenhum motivo ou comentário. Eu acho que justificar o downvote deveria ser obrigatório.

Answer (score 10):

[Não jogar fora os votos legais dados para usuários quando uma conta é removida](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740/140010). A auto remoção nunca deveria fazer isto e a remoção por fraude deveria punir apenas quen foi beneficiário da fraude. Se a conta pertencia a alguém que já tinha uma conta então o voto poderá ser retirado se as duas ou mais contas votaram na mesma postagem, neste caso só um voto continuaria valendo, mas se só uma das contas deu voto ele permaneceria. Precisa de uma meio termo entre apagar a conta e fazer uma fusão de contas.

Na verdade eu acho que na época que se fazia a fusão de contas era mais justo, hoje a pessoa não perde tudo o que deveria e perde coisas que são legítimas.

Comment: Essa eu acho complicado, pq nem todo voto, seja negativo ou positivo é legal, e qq juizo de valor que se faça é sujeito a piorar. Precisa levar em conta o motivo da remoção. Tem caso de usuário que vota positivo em gente bem votada só pra disfarçar, da mesma forma que não presta o voto visado. Remoção por fraude eu sou a favor de que seja completa,  mas com um porém: recálculo do cap (eu acho que esse ultimo é um ponto que merece uma resposta separada aqui - em caso de qq reversão, ajuste, etc, o cap tem que ser reprocessado para não ser injusto).

Answer (score 9):

Acho que vai sair fora do escopo da pergunta.

Mas minha sugestão é que a SE liberasse o [StackOverflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) em língua portuguesa. Tenho alguns colegas que reclamam da falta de mão de obra especializada.

Eu indico o Jobs e eles alegam que a oferta ficará soterrada entre outras do mundo inteiro e quando é aceita na maioria das vezes é respondida por pessoas que não falam a língua portuguesa e por isso é desinteressante.

Fazer uns freela é uma coisa legal, principalmente se você passa o dia inteiro respondendo pergunta no PtSO.

Answer (score 9):

**Estabelecer um tempo de mandato para moderadores.**

Hoje, uma vez que o moderador é eleito permanece no cargo até que solicite para sair (ou seja retirado de lá em situações excepcionais). Naturalmente isso acarreta em um *vício* no estilo de moderação e não necessariamente reflete as atuais demandas da comunidade.

Poderia ser estipulado que o tempo de mandato de um moderador fosse de 2 anos, podendo este ser reeleito quantas vezes conseguir, desde que seguisse o processo de eleição. Acredito que isso abriria espaço para uma maior rotatividade dentro da moderação, refletindo sempre as demandas da comunidade e naturalmente retirando do cargo os moderadores que não são tão ativos.

Comment: Concordo plenamente. Isso incentivaria a produtividade dos mods caso queiram continuar no cargo pois teriam que mostrar serviço. Hoje se um mod perde o interesse mas não abandona completamente as atividades ainda lhe passa pela cabeça inúmeras vezes se uma renuncia ajudaria ou atrapalharia ainda mais o site. Abandonados do jeito que estamos pelos staffs não temos ctz de quanto tempo levaria para que novas eleições fossem feitas, e uma vez renunciado não faria sentido se candidatar novamente, por mais que de repente não aparecessem candidatos à altura do cargo, daí o estrago seria ainda maior.

Comment: Lembrando que eu sempre posto a chance de mudar o estilo, mas todas minhas tentativas não tiveram sucesso. Pelo estado da comunidade tenho dúvidas se daria certo até no SOen. Se a comunidade não está ativa só levaria a pessoas descomprometidas se tornarem moderadoras. A ideia é boa, mas só pode ser implantada com a comunidade em boa saúde. É algo que o @Math já disse, funciona na teoria e eu apoiaria 100% há uns 2 anos, e voltaria apoiar se a comunidade voltar ser ativa, que cai na utopia. O pior que pode acontecer é sair um moderador que faz o que precisa e entrar outro no lugar que não faz

Comment: Essa análise é simples até. Basta uma estimativa de quem estaria na moderação se fosse hoje a eleição e nenhum dos atuais se candidatasse, para determinar se seria bom ou não. Eu tenho uma certa clareza do que aconteceria, pois não é algo que estamos discutindo pela primeira vez (talvez em aberto seja), mas não farei juizo de valor aqui para não atrapalhar o raciocínio individual do pessoal (eu sei que poderia ter reeleição, mas o exercício é trocar tudo para fazer uma análise de risco mais realista).

Comment: Mas também existe o fator de "não funcionará porque eu não concordo com a maneira que será feita". Hoje os moderadores, em conjunto com os usuários mais ativos, possuem uma visão do site. Vejo que muitos moderadores acabam não deixando o cargo porque não seria feito da maneira que lhe agrada. Mas concordo que a mudança drástica na moderação não seria saudável. Poderia ser definido que seja mudado apenas 1 moderador por ano, conforme ir vencendo os mandatos.

Comment: @Woss _"Vejo que muitos moderadores acabam não deixando o cargo porque não seria feito da maneira que lhe agrada."_ confesso que dos nossos aqui, de tudo que já conversamos "entre mods", praticamente todo mundo já disse motivos pra sair ou não sair, mas nunca ouvi nada parecido com esse motivo aí. Talvez eu tenha perdido alguma conversa anterior.

Comment: A ideia é não gerar intrigas aqui, então não me aprofundarei nisso, mas a impressão que já tive é que alguns deles mantém essa postura; pode ser que não intencionalmente, mas acabam passando essa imagem. Com a rotatividade esse assunto nem chega a vir em questão, a moderação muda conforme a comunidade muda e segue o barco.

Comment: Um primeiro passo é a pessoa que quer mudanças apoiar quando eu sugiro mudanças para atender o que a comunidade parece pedir, em vez de ir contra. Começar fazer coisas pra mudar. Um dos erros que as pessoas acreditam é que moderação define o que acontece no site. A comunidade faz isso. Quando há letargia eu pergunto o que fazer, as pessoas opinam e eu faço o que foi definido. Toda mudança precisa de discussão. Um moderador não pode chegar e sair fazendo o que bem entende sem a comunidade querer. Moderador hoje pode de forma limitada cuidar de fraudes e abusos do uso do sistema. ...

Comment: E ainda pode fechar e reabri sozinho, o que está sendo proposto dar mais chance da comunidade fazer isso também e maior ou menor grau. Alguns devem achar que moderamos não punem mais usuários porque não querem, mas aí parece política normal, não tem recursos pra fazer mais. E se querem fazer menos, acho que é um caminho muito errado. Sobre fechamentos a comunidade não está deixando de fechar porque ela quer manter aberto, é porque está letárgica. Porque dá muito trabalho, dor de cabeça, por isso tem proposta até para não aparecer o nome da pessoa.

Comment: Eu aceito ser perseguido direto fazendo o que tem que ser feito. De que adianta mudar moderador se quem for entrar fará pouco ou nada?

Comment: @Maniero Nesse caso parte-se da premissa que sempre entrará alguém que "fará pouco ou nada". Não há como usar isso de base, muito menos assumir que se a pessoa que entrar ficará necessariamente o mandato completo, mesmo fazendo nada. A rotatividade permitiria que a carga de trabalho que hoje está sobre a moderação seja feita por pessoas distintas, sem sobrecarregar ninguém.

Comment: @Woss não há uma caraga de trabalho grande sobre a moderação que um novo moderador resolva. Depois de ver todos os detalhes ficou claro que isto não é o problema. O problema é a falta de atuação da comunidade. Nem a falta de atuação dos CMs é o grande problema, é um problema, mas a falta de atuação da SE como um todo pra fazer tudo isso que estamos propondo é um problema maior. Se entra uma pessoa que faz pouco e sai uma faz muito, é um enorme problema, esfacela de vez. Vale o risco? Tem comunidade que não conseguem fazer eleição porque as pessoas sabem que se entrarem vão fazer nada.

Comment: Eu tenho uma visão um pouco mais completa da situação para afirmar categoricamente que o problema não está na moderação, e sim na comunidade. Eu apoio a ideia quando a comunidade se mostrar mais ativa, quando ela se mostrar coerente. Quando eu faço propostas pra flexibilizar, e fiz várias, até como primeiro passo para flexibilizar mais, tem que ter apoio, não pode a pessoa ser contra e depois falar que a moderação atual está rígida demais. Fica uma proposta incoerente e com jeito de só estar legislando em causa própria, querendo uma vaga. Além do risco, o motivo colocado não faz sentido.

Comment: Um dos preceitos da moderação ser vitalícia é não ser suscetível ao voto toda hora, algo que já se viu problemático na vida normal. A pessoa fica populista para ficar no cargo. Sem a pressão de ter que enfrentar uma eleição ela pode agir como precisa. Moderadores existem para desagradar, esse é o normal, quando moderador está agradando ele está fazendo um trabalho ruim. Se não puder se recandidatar pode resolver esse problema, mas aí fica pior, cada vez mais teremos os piores candidatos, você vai proibindo que fez um bom trabalho de participar. E quem quer continuar tem que agradar,não moderar

Comment: Se as pessoas querem um estilo de moderação diferente é só pedir e ter apoio. Se fizerem isso com coerência vai acontecer. Se for benéfico pra comunidade não tem porque continuar o mesmo estilo. A comunidade o tempo todo pergunta isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7855/101. Eu tentei achar uma forma de aceitar esse conteúdo porque há demanda e de um jeito que a qualidade fosse mantida. Não foi bem aceito. Seria o primeiro passo pra flexibilizar sem perder qualidade. Eu aceitei ter o farde de lidar com isso. E se esntrar outro moderador que não quer isso?Então o assunto não é tão simples

Comment: Não vai entrar alguém e tudo ficará lindo. Claro que muita gente acha que vai e muitos votarão acreditando nisso. Acontece essencialmente em toda eleição. O motivo usado é ruim porque se o problema é estilo, pede para mudar, ganhe apoio, eu pelo menos estou aberto a isto. Sem correr o risco de ir piorando a qualidade por uma burocracia. Levantar a questão é boa, ajuda até haver uma discussão entre os moderadores atuais para melhorar algo que possa não estar bom. Houve uma discussão sobre isto: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/984/140010. Não pode fazer como no Brasil que cria lei pra um caso.

Comment: Ótimo, @Woss. Ainda mais louvável que isso venha de um moderador (acho que você é, né ?). Parabéns.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. Não sou moderador. Fui candidato ano passado, na qual o Bacco se elegeu.

Comment: @Woss , mesmo assim concordo com você. Poderia ocorrer eleições para o quadro de moderadores a cada certo período de tempo. Claro que deveriam estipular critérios para uma pessoa se eleger para moderação, como por exemplo um certo nível de reputação, tempo de conta cadastrada, etc.. Essa questão do cara ser moderador pra sempre soa meio que uma tirania.

Answer (score 9):

Gostaria que votos positivos nas perguntas bonificassem o autor em 5 pontos de reputação e nas respostas em 10 pontos. Como era até alguns meses atrás.

No início do site, em 2008, a recompensa era de 10 pontos tanto para a pergunta quanto para a resposta, e isso foi modificado em 2011 quando o Jeff Atwood propôs o modelo de bonificação menor para as perguntas, dando sua explicação nesse post: [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Eu particularmente achei a explicação dele muito mais interessante do que a da Sara Chipps, que em novembro de 2019, escreveu explicando o porquê da decisão de reverter a modificação do Jeff, e voltar a fazer que os votos em perguntas valessem 10 pontos, se igualando ao voto nas respostas. Na explicação dela, resumidamente ela diz que *"perguntas são importantes"*: [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/)

Relacionado: [Quais foram as consequências de aumentar o valor do voto em perguntas para 10?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8120/3117)

Comment: Tem uma característica comum nas pessoas que você mencionou. As duas pessoas são muito consistentes no que fazem. O nível das publicações segue um padrão constante. E no caso do Jeff o padrão é de postagens de boa qualidade.

Comment: Eu acho que perguntas deveriam ter até menos que 5 pontos e o negativo nelas consumir mais que 2 pontos. Em perguntas tem menos votos para "eliminara concorrência", e como já falei antes, o grande ganho de quem pergunta é receber uma resposta, não deveria dar tanta pontuação. Dá se realmente a pergunta é muito boa, mas tira bem se ela for ruim. Premia a boa como a Sara quer, e pune quem faz o oposto. Dá pra pensar em um sistema mais sofisticado que eu acho que já falei antes em algum lugar. Só conta ponto se tiver alguns ups e cada down recebido exige mais ups para gerar pontos.

Answer (score 9):

Poder comentar para mais de uma pessoa que esteja participando da mesma publicação usando o arroba `@`, hoje nos campos de comentários estamos limitados a um comentário por pessoa, então só posso escrever:

```
@fulano etc etc etc etc
```

Mas tem vezes que algo precisa ser direcionado para mais de uma pessoa, como:

```
@fulano etc etc etc etc (cc @beltrano)
```

Seria interessante que pelo menos pudéssemos comentar para 3 pessoas (mais que isto seria exagero e poderia até ser mal usado)

**Relacionado** https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8199/3635

Comment: Concordo caso seja no meta. Lembre o "deve evitar discussões nos comentários".

Comment: @ramaral sempre tentamos evitar, seria uma maravilha se o publico atual entendesse de primeira, e se os de boa vontade e pouca experiencia evitassem de comentar sem ter certeza, por isto muitas vezes temos que comentar para o autor e para outro usuário o porque de um comentário anterior ser problematico, ter que repetir 3 vezes um mesmo comentário é que me parece desperdício. Claro que digo isso em "respostas", em perguntas 2 seria mais que o suficiente, já que o AP sempre é notificado do que vai em sua pergunta.

Answer (score 8):

Quando a pessoa fosse responder e tivesse um score menor que 5000 (5 mil), **ou um valor que a "comunidade" julgasse razoável** (até medalhas como parâmetro), deliberadamente no momento de responder uma pergunta apareceria uma janela modal para confirmar a resposta, com os dizeres:

> Este campo é somente para respostas que resolvam o problema ou para complementar uma resposta existente na mesma pergunta, acaso você estiver:
>
> - adicionando detalhes a pergunta
> - dando uma opinião
> - fazendo uma pergunta ou comentário ao autor da pergunta ("AP")
>
> Então não use este campo

No modal deveria ter botões bem explícitos:

> [Estou respondendo (Confirmar em verde)]
>
> [Não é uma resposta (cancelar, em vermelho)]

Isto porque muita gente, mesmo que a maioria das pessoas não notem, usa o campo de resposta erroneamente

Comment: Já não tem algo parecido com isto, ainda que para uma reputação menor?

Comment: @Maniero não acho que da forma que existe seja tão "intuitiva", mas faz muito tempo q não tenho score baixo, talvez algo tenha mudado, não sei como é hoje

Comment: @Maniero acho que tópicos sempre ajudam na leitura, apesar de parecer um texto grande, não acho que realmente seja, tirei algumas frases para simplificar, no geral me parece que não ficou tão grande.

Comment: Poderia adicionar mais um item a lista do que não fazer na resposta: "Dando um chute com o que eu acho que é mas nem entendo direito"?

Answer (score 8):

Avaliar negativamente (o mesmo que reportar) usuário que estão usando de forma errada a **"fila de análises"**.

Não estou falando de sinalizar, estou falando de avaliar para que a comunidade decidisse e o próprio sistema barrasse certos usuários, por exemplo, votar negativamente (positivo não existiria) em uma "ação especifica do usuário", se ele começasse a receber muitos downvotes em diferentes postagens o sistema com o tempo avaliaria e o vetaria de usar a fila de analise especifica que ele atuou, lembrando que temos mais de uma "fila de analise" (fila de fechamento, abertura, edição, etc).

O motivo disto é que tem muitos usuários que entendem pouco ou nada das tecnologias aparecem nas postagens da fila e as vezes votam para `Manter aberta` quando a pergunta deveria ser fechada ou votam `Fechar` quando não é realmente um problema.

Também tem muitas aprovações de edição que na verdade quem editou acabou modificando o código das perguntas (eu vi isso algumas vezes), mas na fila tais edições foram aprovadas, o que foi péssimo, por sorte eu tenho score que me permite editar sem confirmação, então eu fiz o rollback para corrigir.

Esta sugestão é porque acredito que seria muito importante podermos **avaliar quem avalia** também.

Answer (score 8):

Moderadores precisam de mais privilégios principalmente para combater fraude. Mesmo que precise da anuência de outro(s) moderador(es) para efetivar. E que seja bem auditado.

Isto é necessário porque ficou claro que os CMs não dão conta de todo trabalho que estão nas suas costas, principalmente para os sites internacionais. E agora com menos CMs, complicou de vez.

Me lembro de de alguma conversa que mudaria algo (não sei bem o que era) para os sites que ajudaria isto, mas como sempre ficou na conversa.

Ao mesmo tempo para não sobrecarregar os moderadores a comunidade precisa ganhar privilégios como proposto em [1](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8159/101) e [2](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8157/101).

Answer (score 8):

Quando mais cedo o AP tomar consciência de que a sua pergunta tem problemas mais cedo poderá corrigir.
Muitos não se apercebem que a pergunta foi votada para fechar.

Tal como é adicionado um comentário quando há voto de fecho como duplicata, o mesmo deveria ser feito para os outros motivos. O comentário indicaria o motivo de fechamento e seria anónimo ou não(requer discussão).

Comment: Concordo. Da mesma maneira que sentimos a ausência de transparência por parte da SE, acho que a falta de transparência por parte da comunidade também afeta negativamente, principalmente em relação à motivação do voto, não necessariamente ao usuário. Acho que o comentário sendo anônimo ou não poderia funcionar.

Comment: E de preferência em pt-br

Answer (score 8):

Precisa voltar ter números (desta vez do jeito certo) para indicar pendências da lista de tarefas. Quando trocaram por uma bolinha acabou o senso de urgência que o número indicava.

Não sei se volta consertar porque uma vez que as pessoas acostumam com o errado não é fácil ir pro certo.

Answer (score 8):

Antigamente existia uma opção no Stack Overflow de sinalizar que um comentário era uma possível resposta de uma pergunta.

Como isto faz muito tempo, não lembro exatamente como funcionava na prática para promover aquele comentário como uma resposta. Mas vejo com frequência perguntas sem respostas na qual um dos comentários já traz informação suficiente para ser considerada uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Tem certeza que existia? Eu acho que vi em algum lugar pedindo para criar isto. Não sei se é bom porque em geral o comentário não tem a qualidade que uma resposta exige, e mesmo que tenha será muito raro acontecer.

Comment: @Maniero não dou certeza, mas tenho como vaga lembrança que eu usava este recurso logo que entrei no SO (mais de 6 anos atrás).

Answer (score 8):

Permitir criar um conjunto próprio de [comentários enlatados](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/707/coment%C3%A1rios-enlatados-para-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-comuns) para ser aplicado nos comentários de uma forma bem fácil. Algo parecido com o que o Github fornece nos comentários dos PRs.

Este recurso pode ser liberado depois de uma determinada pontuação do usuário.

Comment: Isto é uma especialização do que coloquei aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8144/101.

Answer (score 8):

Gostaria que votos em publicações no site meta recebessem notificação na caixa de entrada assim como os votos em publicações no site principal recebem.

Não temos reputação (explícita) no meta, mas nem por isso deveríamos deixar de ser notificados quando recebemos votos nessas publicações. Ser notificado disso pode ser importante para descobrirmos que alguma publicação nossa recebeu atenção seja lá por qual motivo, vale a pena que o autor volte lá e veja se alguma discussão voltou a tona e ele possa contribuir melhorando a resposta ou comentando em novas respostas que surgiram após a discussão reacender.

Relacionado: [Make voting activity on your posts available on site metas (what you would get from rep if metas had rep)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167648/229289)

Answer (score 7):

Ao adicionar Stack Snippet deveria haver uma checagem mais ou menos inteligente para detectar se o snippet funciona, mas isto somente para usuário com menos de 5000 de score, **ou um valor que a "comunidade" julgasse razoável** (até medalhas como parâmetro).

Por exemplo o usuário adiciona o stacksnippet com código PHP, o que não faz sentido, ou somente código, neste caso emitiria um modal para confirmar com os seguintes dizeres:

> ```
> Sua postagem aparentemente está usando o Stack Snippet de forma incorreta,
> veja em [como usar o Stack Snippet](link para o FAQ)
> ```

Com os seguintes botões:

> ```
> [Postar mesmo assim (confirmar, em verde)] [Corrigir postagem (cancelar, em vermelho)]
> ```

Comment: Eu acho que muita verificação automática precisa ser feita. O SO foi criado em um momento completamente diferente. Site que não usa IA tá ultrapassado. Falo isso não porque essa questão precise de IA, mas a maioria das melhorias pra simplificar a tarefa da comunidade envolve.

Comment: @Maniero o engraçado é que começou como um site para programadores, logo coisas como IA no site deveriam ser já uma realidade, mas o site apesar de visualmente melhor ainda parece muito atrasado em diversos aspectos ... **é tão irônico :/**

Answer (score 7):

Poder ignorar o usuário. Tem gente que não merece crédito algum. Estou colocando aqui porque ainda não e resolveram fazer e seria bom dar apoio aqui também, mas [já está proposto no metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/140010).

Comment: Só por curiosidade, o que aconteceria se esse usuário respondesse a pergunta? 
- Não apareceria  a resposta?
- Aparecia a resposta como se um usuário fake tivesse respondido?
Ou o  usuário bloqueado pela pessoa que perguntou não pode responder nem comentar na pergunta?

Comment: Esses detalhes precisariam ser discutidos se isso fosse implementado (na verdade estamos mais brincando aqui, não vejo nada disso acontecendo, ainda mais depois dos últimos acontecimentos na rede), e poderia ser que a pessoa escolhesse o que ela queria ignorar, poderia até fazer uma resposta não aparecer para quem pediu pra ignorar certo usuário. Não é algo que pensei muito sobre, mas achei interessante que tenha uma proposta já existente.

Comment: Entendi, dei uma olhada lá no link que você postou e me parece que metade quer e metade não quer isso no SO.

Comment: Sim, é algo polêmico. Pode ou não ser bom, eu nem postei por muita ênfase, foi mais pra contribuir com algo que vi e há algum interesse. Eu nem sei se eu usaria o recurso. Até porque eu acho que no momento que a pessoa se torna muito inconveniente, como moderador eu deveria tomar outras providências.

Answer (score 6):

Deveríamos nos concentrar mais no foco inicial do site que era ter mais respostas canônicas, e por isso deveria dar valor para perguntas que ajudem produzir esse conteúdo.

Isto implica em considerar mais as coisas duplicatas e não aceitar nada que seja minimamente amplo, porque o amplo dificulta algo ser duplicado.

Quanto mais aceitamos perguntas que dependem de muitas variáveis menos estamos produzindo conhecimento útil para muitos e mais estamos produzindo ajuda para uma única pessoa. O diferencial do site sempre foi o oposto.

Pra mim tudo que é solução individual é ruído.

Me lembro que o site foi concebido para ser um meio termos entre um fórum e uma wiki, ou seja, partindo de uma dúvida real de uma pessoa produzir o conteúdo para beneficiar muitos.

Trocamos a quantidade pela qualidade.

Existem sites para solução de problemas específicos, o SOpt não deveria entrar nesse nicho.

Answer (score 6):

[Significado do voto no META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1668/101)

Este é um caso que eu acho que precisa de modificação do sistema, mas se for só tradução acho que a comunidade podia fazer. Acho importante no mínimo informar que o voto no meta é diferente. Muitos não vão ler, mas ajuda.

Eu acho que da mesma forma que acho que o sistema tem que ajudar o usuário novo usar melhor o site principal, precisa ensinar usar o meta com suas especificidades.

[Já foi negado antes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75049/140010), mas não acho que precisa ser exatamente como foi pedido no metão.

Answer (score 6):

Perguntas devem iniciar fechadas. A comunidade vota para abrir a pergunta.

Pelo menos para usuário novatos (e pode ter uma pontuação alta para considerar que não é novato). E deve poder remover o privilégio de usuário mais antigo.

Claro que ele precisa ser notificado disto e explicar bem porque ocorre assim. Seria interessante criar mecanismos para que a pergunta seja aberta sem tanta dificuldade. Mas não pode abrir tão fácil se receber alguma indicação que ela deve continuar fechada.

Comment: Talvez fosse interessante fazer com que perguntas de usuários que receberam penalidades ou tiveram muitas perguntas fechadas pela comunidade começassem fechadas. Isso poderia impedir abusos frequentes

Answer (score 6):

Diferenciar quem votou em que na hora de fechar, não faz sentido manter tudo como uma coisa só, ainda mais que tem caso que diferencia. Junto com a [possibilidade de continuar votando em algo fechado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8156/101) ajuda muito indicar para o autor o problema que foi encontrado.

[Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/140010).

Nem estou propondo (ainda, mas é de se pensar), mas a pessoa poder votar em mais de um motivo pode ser uma boa, mesmo que conte um só voto. Há muitos casos de vários problemas na pergunta, então resolver um não adianta muita coisa. O ideal é poder retirar um motivo  de fechamento quando este seja resolvido, mas não os outros.

Comment: Mostrar todos (ou pelo menos os principais) no card de aviso de fechamento também seria interessante, não adianta dizer que tem vários problemas se o usuário só vê o mais votado

Comment: A proposta é justamente esta.

Comment: Não tinha entendido então

Answer (score 5):

Vale qualquer coisa mesmo? Vale coisas muito abstratas? Se valer...

Voltar os usuários que eram muito ativos, que produziam qualidade em tudo, não só respostas. Desta forma o trabalho de moderação (no sentido geral) seria mais mais distribuído, cada um faria o que faz melhor. Tornaria [o site mais feliz](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8142/101) por ter mais respostas boas e que ensinam mais.

Parte do problema é não ter mais uma comunidade grande ativa e com pessoas de qualidade, trazendo a real diversidade (não essa que algumas pessoa pregam que é usurpação do termo). Isto pararia de sobrecarregar poucas pessoas. Eu estou até repensando sobre a questão de reduzir os votos para o fechamento. Está difícil ter até um voto para fechar, se for simétrico provavelmente é melhor nem testar.

A comunidade ajudava salvar algo. Hoje isto quase não acontece. É verdade que que está mais difícil, as pessoas que perguntam não estão ajudando.

Eu sei que isto não vai rolar, mas é uma forma de colocar o que eu acho que seja o real problema da comunidade funcionar pior que no passado. Ainda que isto não seja todo o problema.

Comment: Pode clarificar o que está propondo aqui? É a redução do numero de votos para fechar?

Comment: Não, aqui estou desabafando mais que propondo algo :D Estou tentando dizer que este é talvez o maior problema do site atualmente. Não tem o que fazer, mesmo que fizesse algo as pessoas não voltarão, elas desencanaram, perceberam que não vale o esforço de ajudar um monte de mal agradecido que não se esforça em nada. Essas pessoas ajudavam, cada um um pouco, o site ficar melhor, eles votavam em coisas boas (hoje é raro as pessoas fazerem isto), elas editavam, votavam para fechar e reabrir, comentavam bem. Hoje isto está na mão de poucas pessoas,ficou tão pesado e tão ineficaz que reduziram carga

Comment: Durante todo o beta do site (que foi bem longo) gastei muitas horas dos meus dias respondendo, perguntando e tentando ajudar a comunidade, mas eu desanimei muito por causa que muitas vezes eu gastava meia hora elaborando uma resposta e na hora de postar tinham fechado a pergunta por qualquer motivo....

Answer (score 5):

Acho que isto tem um peso menor, mas um problema que ocorre muito é a pessoa postar uma resposta que na verdade deveria ser uma pergunta e deveria poder converter para pergunta.

Não acho tão importante porque a maioria das vezes que isto ocorre a forma postada é muito ruim e a conversão se daria em uma pergunta ruim. Mas ainda poderia converter e fechar, como forma de instruir o usuário do erro que cometeu e dando a chance dele melhorar a pergunta que agora pelo menos está classificada do jeito correto. Hoje a resposta é apagada e fica assim mesmo.

Comment: Saberia informar se o usuário ao menos é notificado que a resposta foi excluída?

Comment: Não é, é bem ruim. Na verdade uma outra sugestão é notificar mais os usuários do que está acontecendo, a falta de transparência em nome de não irritar o usuário tem causado vários problemas, embora possa ter evitado algumas brigas.

Answer (score 5):

Deve haver mais incentivo da pessoa ser membro ativo da comunidade. Não pode ser invasivo como as redes sociais são que não param de mandar notificações e e-mails quando você se afasta, mas deve tentar mostrar as vantagens de pesquisar algo, ler o que tem de bom no passado, como aprender com o conteúdo existente, como pode dar de volta o que recebe ajudando curar o conteúdo.

Precisa de um ponto de equilíbrio entre não ser chato e não abandonar o usuário.

Uma das coisas que vai desincentivando os usuários mais ativos é a falta de votos. Poderia por exemplo avisar a pessoa que mesmo aceitando pode votar na resposta escolhida. Pode avisar isto depois e ela ainda não tem direito a voto.

Answer (score 5):

Alguns parâmetros usados para dar medalha devem ser proporcionais ao tamanho do site.

Tem medalha que é muito fácil ganhar no SOen mas quase impossível no SOpt e outros sites menores.

Alguns exemplos:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/334/lifeboat
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/61/publicist
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/populist (parece fácil, mas tem muito caso que se aproxima disso mas não chega)

Sem falar nas medalhas de *tags*, mas não sei se essas são tão importantes assim, tem bastante, pode ser suficiente.

Não estou dizendo que essas são as que devem ter parâmetros mudados, podem ser essas e outras, algumas dessas não mudar, mas eu acho que medalhas que são dadas por méritos e dependem do exercício de terceiros para alcançar o resultado deveriam ser mais fáceis em sites menores. Pode ser até para medalhas que já foram dadas milhares, e provavelmente deveria dar mais. O problema não é quase não dar e sim dar menos do que deveria porque exige um esforço que não acontece por aqui. Os parâmetros foram criados só para o SOen.

Answer (score 5):

Ao digitar algo em uma postagem o `@<nome de usuário>`, seja **sugerido** um autocomplete com perfis que usam o tal nome para que possa gerar automaticamente o link apontando para o perfil.

Eu entendo que alguns podem dizer que o importante é o conteúdo, mas acho que valorizar bons autores de conteúdo é importante, principalmente se o tal autor cria muito conteúdo útil e até apresenta coisas desconhecidas pela maioria, hoje então fiz a seguinte postagem:

```
... SAPI (Server Application Programming Interface, neste caso são algumas
instruções especiais como o X-Send citado pelo colega @Bacco que só
correm do lado servidor ...
```

Eu entendo que mais de um usuário pode ter o mesmo nome no site, mas por isso a sugestão do autocomplete, semelhante ao do facebook, facilitando tornar o texto acima em:

```
... SAPI (Server Application Programming Interface, neste caso são algumas
instruções especiais como o X-Send citado pelo
colega https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco que só
correm do lado servidor ...
```

E o link diretamente assim seria com um magic-link (semelhante o que ocorre com links de **"perguntas"**), seria renderizado como:

```
... SAPI (Server Application Programming Interface, neste caso são algumas
instruções especiais como o X-Send citado pelo
colega <a href="https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco">@bacco</a> que só
correm do lado servidor ...:
```

Lembrando que se o autor mudar o nick seria automaticamente ajustado (como os links de perguntas), exemplo mudou o nick para `dionisio`, então seria renderizado automaticamente em:

```
... SAPI (Server Application Programming Interface, neste caso são algumas
instruções especiais como o X-Send citado pelo
colega <a href="https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/70/dionisio">@dionisio</a> que só
correm do lado servidor ...:
```

É um recurso mínimo e realmente pouquíssimas vezes seria usado e só alguns usariam e claro que concordo que tá fácil fazer manualmente, mas ainda sim fica como sugestão, lembrando, se acharem que isto é um recurso um tanto quando dispensável então negativem e comentem se acharem necessário, mas aqui os votos já serão bem claros sobre (não) ser um bom recurso.

Answer (score 4):

Não é prioridade, mas eu gosto da ideia do Teams que você pode indicar quem você quer notificar para tentar responder uma pergunta.

Isto deveria ser configurável, ou seja, a pessoa diz quem pode notificá-lo. Quem tenha x pontos na *tag* tal ou geral, ou que tenha um medalha y, ou outro critério. E ser notificado só das *tags* que você autorizar, ou quem sabe autorizar só algumas pessoas específicas, ou ainda tirar algumas que você percebe que não tem bom senso. Claro que pode não aceitar qualquer notificação.

Quem sabe pode deixar a pessoa pedir para notificar com qualquer pontuação e só quem está autorizado a fazê-lo pela pessoa é que pode efetivar a notificação, assim a pessoa pode expressar seu desejo mas não importunar a não ser que alguém veja que o pedido faz sentido e é justo, que ela deve se interessar. Mais ou menos o que acontece com edição.

Answer (score 3):

Uma coisa que me incomoda muito atualmente, é o fato de perguntas de mais de 1 ou 2 anos aparecerem na página inicial com o comentário *Modificada por: Comunidade*. ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212188/json-php-javascript))

Várias destas perguntas já foram inclusive respondidas, porém o autor não marcou a resposta como aceita (as vezes ele mesmo respondeu com a resolução deste problema, mas não marcou a resposta como aceita).

Acredito que essa medida seja adotada para que membros da comunidade possam prover uma resposta para um desses problemas, mas parece que elas são "perguntas zumbis" na página inicial, visto que pouco tempo depois somem sem nenhuma resposta ou novidade, eu já tentei responder estas perguntas, mas por muitas vezes o autor nunca da o feedback do meu contato (penso que nem acesse mais o site muitas vezes).

Seria interessante adotar algum critério para trazer as questões nessa situação para a página inicial novamente.

Comment: Existe um critério... veja mais em [O que significa “modificada pela Comunidade”?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1953/5878)

Comment: @Woss, inclui um exemplo que está na página inicial da comunidade neste momento

Comment: Tem mais sobre em [O que acontece com perguntas “eternas”?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4269/5878)

Comment: Em geral se precisa de interação com o autor é porque a pergunta deveria estar fechada.

Comment: @woss seu primeiro comentário me fez lembrar de algo que eu gostaria que mudasse no site

Answer (score 2):

Isto é uma ideia somente para os sites principais e não para os METAs

Quando clicasse em compartilhar facebook ou twitter:

> [image: compartilha postagem]

na mensagem pré pronta fosse adicionando ao menos duas hashtags que seriam baseado nas tags adicionadas a pergunta, mesmo que esteja compartilhando uma resposta, então no twitter ao invés de aparecer algo como:

> ```
> Alterar Valores ChartJS [fechada] https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/430611/3635?stw=2
> ```

Iria aparecer isto:

> ```
> Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/3635?stw=2 #php #mysql
> ```

Note que a pergunta original [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/3635) contém 5 tags, mas 5 seria um exagero, duas estaria bom, claro que dá pra fazer manualmente, eu faço, mas seria interessante já deixar isto padrão.

---

Cross-post: [Add hashtag with tag of question in 'share' before posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275752/198279)

Comment: No caso do Facebook também se poderia usar hashtags, já que hoje em dia ele também reconhece isso

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim, é o que eu disse, "facebook ou twitter", eu sei que raramente as pessoas postam, mas na época que sugeri isto no Metão eu estava compartilhando muito, então pra mim é útil. Fiquei chateado que recebi uns comentários tratando isso como "qualquer coisa", lógico que pra eles era qualquer coisa, porque provavelmente nem compartilhar (com tag ou sem) eles usavam, então eu estava falando de uma necessidade de quem usa a ferramenta e não de quem não usa, mas foi como conversar com as paredes.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado veja só o tipo de mensagem que eu recebo: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275752/add-hashtag-with-tag-of-question-in-share-before-posting?noredirect=1#comment1148587_275752 -- isso só porque fiz uma edição rapida, o cara já veio com acusações. O povo de lá é sem noção, não resolvem quase nada e por uma coisa que não cheira e nem fede o cara ficou se "doendo".

Answer (score 2):

Adicionaria uma opção de escolher o visual do site e colocaria LIGHT MODE e DARK MODE.

É algo simples mas eu prefiro **Dark Mode** quando tem nos sites, não cansa tanto meus olhos.

Como exemplo  de Dark Mode segue o site do Jovem Nerd - https://jovemnerd.com.br/

Comment: Pra quem não deseja esperar https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark, Stylish é um addon pra diferentes navegadores, e então você escolhe o tema, a vantagem disto ai é que é comunitário e você pode colaborar com melhorias.

Comment: Instalei aqui, ficou muito bom, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Poder seguir a atividade de outros usuários no site. Embora possamos fazer isto por *Feed*, seria muito mais cômodo fazer isto pelo próprio site.

Imagino que isto gere resistência na comunidade por fazer com que o SO caminhe na direção de algum tipo de rede social.

Comment: Não acho importante, mas não sou contra, hoje pode ser até vantajoso.

Comment: Se for ter, seria bom poder combinar usuário e tag, não só um ou só outro

Answer (score 1):

Algumas coisas nos comentários não deveriam contar no limite de texto digitado, por exemplo:

- nome de outro usuário
- `**negrito**` e `*itálico*`
- amostra de código
- Remover/desconsiderar espaços e quebras de linha extras dentro de "amostra de código"
- Remover/desconsiderar espaços e quebras de linha extras no começo da string e após a string

Um comentário assim por exemplo:

```
Olá **Fulano**, com o código `var foo = baz;` você poderá fazer *X operação*
```

O comentário de exemplo acima hoje acusa como tendo 76 caracteres, isto para o limitador nos faz "perder" 8 caracteres, mas isto é apenas um exemplo simples, em um comentário mais extenso isso pode ser o fator que determina entre eu ser obrigado a fazer um comentário "extensão" do primeiro, que muitas vezes fica algo como:

> **cacilds vidis** litro abertis. In *elementis* mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Em pé sem cair, deitado sem dormir, sentado sem
>   cochilar e fazendo pose. @Praesent vel viverra nisi. Mauris aliquet
>   nunc non turpis scelerisque, eget. Nullam volutpat risus nec leo
>   commodo, `ut interdum diam laoreet. Sed non consequat odio. Posuere
>   libero varius. Nullam a nisl ut ante blandit hendrerit. Aenean sit
>   amet nisi. Per aumento de cachacis, eu reclamis`. Leite de capivaris,
>   leite de mula manquis sem cabeça. **Sapien in monti** palavris qui num
>   significa nadis i pareci latim. Pindureta *quium dia nois paga*.

No exemplo excedi em 3 caracteres o limite, logo é provável que eu teria que separar em dois só para adicionar as vezes um paragrafo final, algo como:

Comentário 1:

> Mussum Ipsum, **cacilds vidis** litro abertis. In *elementis* mé pra
>   quem é amistosis quis leo. Em pé sem cair, deitado sem dormir, sentado
>   sem cochilar e fazendo pose. @Praesent vel viverra nisi. Mauris aliquet
>   nunc non turpis scelerisque, eget. Nullam volutpat risus nec leo
>   commodo, `ut interdum diam laoreet. Sed non consequat odio. Posuere
>   libero varius. Nullam a nisl ut ante blandit hendrerit. Aenean sit
>   amet nisi. Per aumento de cachacis, eu reclamis`. Leite de capivaris,
>   leite de mula manquis sem cabeça. **Sapien in monti** palavris qui num
>   significa nadis i pareci latim.[...]

Comentário 2:

> [...] Manduma pindureta *quium dia nois paga*.

Mas se nem nome de usuário como `@username`, negrito, itálico e "amostra de código" fossem desconsiderados teríamos descontado 15 caracteres, o que já ajudaria bastante.

E na prática não é tão complicado de resolver, nem no front-end nem no back-end (não que eu queira dar palpites para os desenvolvedores da SE), por exemplo:

- Ao invés de (provavelmente fazem algo semelhante a isto):

  ```
   if (comment.value.length > 600) {
      //Invalido
   }
  ```

  Faria isto (mais ou menos não chequei todas possibilidades, provavelmente as regex aqui são ineficientes, é só pra exemplificar):

  ```
  let value = comment.value;

  //Remove espaços desnecessários
  value = value.trim();

  //Remove "markdown" de amostra de código
  value = value.replace(/(^|\s)[`](.*)[`]($| )/g, "$1$2$3");

  //Remove "markdown" de negrito
  value = value.replace(/(^|\s)\*\*(.*)\*\*($| )/g, "$1$2$3");

  //Remove "markdown" de italico (* e _)
  value = value.replace(/(^|\s)[*_](.*)[*_]($| )/g, "$1$2$3");

  if (value.length > 600) {
  //Invalido
  }
  ```

E no back-end se tiver um conversor de markdown para HTML bastaria usar uma lib de DOM para obter somente o texto

**Relacionado:** https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8198/3635

Comment: Não concordo. Tendo em conta a função dos comentários o comprimento actual é mais do que suficiente. Se o comentário necessita de ser longo algo está mal. No meta ainda posso admitir.

Comment: @ramaral tem muitos espaços que poderiam já ser descontados, independente do markdown, porque as pessoas não sabem usar bem ou realmente é complicado ficar ajustando, vocÊ tem experiência no site e sabe como é complicado orientar as pessoas, muitas vezes o comentário se estende sim, mesmo que pareça um problema do comentário na maioria acaba sendo problema de como explicar todos pontos, saber escrever e ainda ter que contornar o problema de má vontade no entendimento de muitos usuários. Outra coisa é a experiência que as pessoas não tem em comentar e remover o que é desnecessário.

Answer (score 1):

Essa ideia seria um complemento [dessa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8143/se-voc%C3%AA-pudesse-alterar-qualquer-coisa-no-site-o-que-mudaria/8161#8161)...

As respostas do meta devem conter uma e somente uma ideia/solução/opinião e, depois de um tempo, quando atingir um número mínimo de votos positivos e tendo uma certa relação de positivos e negativos (tudo a ser decidido pela comunidade, por exemplo, uma semana ou um mês, 5 ou 10 votos e relação 50%/50% ou 40%/60%, etc) a ideia/solução/opinião deve ser colocada em prática (se possível), provavelmente, por um moderador

Relacionada: [O Meta não deveria ser mais ágil?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7815/o-meta-n%c3%a3o-deveria-ser-mais-%c3%a1gil)

Answer (score 0):

Esta começa entrar na questão de mudar bastante o site.

Devemos ter outras formas de contribuir com conteúdo de qualidade, canônico, que reforce o aspecto comunitário e não ajuda individual e que não precisa ser só perguntas e respostas, então algumas páginas poderiam ter outro formato, desde que tenha valor para desenvolvedores de software.

Não vou entrar em detalhe porque sei que não será implantado, mas se tiver indicação dá para discutir.

Comment: O que sugere como outro formato? Wiki?

Comment: Outros em geral ,não apenas. Se tem como gerar bom conteúdo deveria contemplar. Eu não acho que a SE está no ramo de Q&A e sim de conteúdo para devs, só falta eles perceberem isto.

Answer (score -2):

Eu tentaria promover mais o chat dentro do site, para que mais pessoas que não participam passem a usá-lo.

De imediato, pensei em **criar no chat uma sala semanal com o assunto da semana**. Lá todos podem conversar sobre o tal assunto. Exemplo: "REST não é RPC", "Você precisa do Spring?", etc.

Podem ser assuntos polêmicos ou comuns, para chamar a atenção dos usuários e mostrar que o chat existe. Claro que isto precisaria de um destaque no site e, também, alguma moderação. Depois de encerrada a discussão isto ficaria disponível e bem visível, listado algum lugar do site para consultas futuras.

Acho que seria um chamativo para quem visita pouco o SO e ver como os outros desenvolvedores pensam sobre determinado assunto, quando normalmente a maioria de nós fica preso em um círculo muito pequeno de conhecimento compartilhado e, muitas vezes, viciado.

Comment: Por que tantos negativos? Só para entender mesmo.

Comment: Eu não posso afirmar por todos, mas o que me parece que pode ser o caso é que não é uma ideia "pratica" e nem realmente é um problema e raramente isso conseguiria se seguir, só se fosse feito pelos usuarios da comunidade, mas em questão do site, que depende da empresa, se eles o fizessem raramente iria funcionar de maneira ideal como deseja e ainda precisaria de um CM que fale portuguÊs, o que não temos.

Answer (score -5):

Uma ideia que sempre defendo é a **justificativa dos downvotes** (quando dados) em perguntas e respostas. (Se possível, poderia ser dado **justificativas no upvote também**).

A justificativa poderia ser bem breve, só uma explicação do que o usuário não gostou naquela pergunta. Poderia até ter uma lista de opções nas quais o usuário, que deu um **downvote** em uma pergunta, possa selecionar uma delas. (uma lista colocada em um select, por exemplo)

Acho que com isso o usuário que elaborou a pergunta saberia em que parte na formulação da pergunta ele errou (se ele achar que errou), e consequentemente ele poderia modificar (consertar) a pergunta de acordo com aquele **Feedback que ele vem recebendo nos downvotes**.

Acho que o **downvote** no **Stackoverflow** é muito **banalizado**. Assim como o **upvote**.

Acho que isso com certeza diminuiriam as participações dos usuários nos **votes** e **downvotes** (e o aumento e diminuição de reputação dos usuários diminuiria drásticamente), porém, acho que o que presamos aqui não é a reputação de 'fulano' e 'siclano' e sim o quanto aquela pergunta ou resposta possa ser útil para o usuário em si e para a comunidade.

- Hoje acho muito fácil e cômodo a pessoa apertar um simples botãozinho e dar um vote ou downvote em uma pergunta ou resposta, que muita das vezes, é de extrema importância para quem a reproduziu.

Comment: Quase todo mundo leva pro lado pessoal, isso já foi discutido, quem tem muita experiencia no site sabe que se expor na maioria das vezes é problema, devido a imaturidade de muitos que não levam como critica, mas sim como ataque, mesmo não sendo, se isto funcionasse a anos já teria sido implantado, porque inclusive é motivo de debates no METÃO a anos, mas só quem tem menos experiencia acha isto uma boa ideia. Leituras: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/3635 / https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4701/3635

Comment: Sim, e estou justificando minha discordância do porque isto é ou não uma boa ideia, do mesmo jeito que tem em outras respostas desta pergunta. O debate é valido aqui no META.

Comment: Aproveite e veja: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvotes+comentar e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4162/3635

Comment: Aqui foi só um post para colocar situações de que "se pudéssemos mudar o que quisermos", o que mudaríamos. Essa história de "mas só quem tem menos experiencia acha isto uma boa ideia" já virou argumento passado e repetitivo. Mude essa cabeça de sempre ficar rotulando pessoas entre mais e menos experientes. Você, como "mais experiente" era pra saber disso mais que qualquer um. Isso aqui é uma comunidade e não existe mais espaço pra esse tipo de argumento raso(com todo o respeito) e infantilde ficar diferenciando usuários. Minha resposta foi uma supondo uma situação imaginária que eu acho ideal.

Comment: Sim, todos posts são situação imaginarias, pode ler um a um, o site meta é um lugar para debates, e eu não estou rotulando ninguém, estou apenas demonstrando que isto o que você imagina seria de fato um problema se aplicado, porque isto sendo uma ideia para imaginação ou não ainda sim é um desejo de muitos e estou explicando de forma educada e sem rotular nada que isto é uma experiencia das comunidades, tanto SOpt quanto SOen quanto outras que seria mais problematico do que funcional. As pessoas em maioria levam sim pro lado pessoal downvotes, fora que essa ideia seria burocracia.

Comment: E pode ver, tem sugestões minhas aqui mesmo que também receberam comentários dizendo que não seria uma boa ideia e eu não levei a mal, apenas debati apontando o pq ainda acho uma boa ideia. Então não tem pq você levar a mal, nem levar pro lado pessoal e nem nada do tipo.

Comment: Eu não levei a mal, cara. Até a parte que vc citou aquele papo de "somente que é menos experiente, bla, bla, bla...". E o argumentos de muitos usuários aqui é sempre esse. Parece que se sentem superiores aos outros usuários. Aqui é todo mundo farinha do mesmo saco, brother.  Respeito opiniões divergentes, porém, sem colocat  rótulos.

Comment: Você é um cara bom, Guilherme. Dá pra perceber a sua diferença para alguns usuários aqui. Porém a diferença está cada vez diminuindo mais. Não se iguale.

Comment: ... digo, diferença de comportamento.

Comment: Eu entendi o que disse, mas eu não estou me igualando a ninguém, eu pessoalmente acho que você apenas interpretou mal o que eu disse, estou tentando lhe passar a experiencia do que eu tenho para que você não precise trilhar o caminho das pedras que eu fui obrigado, alguns caminhos das pedras evitei graças a outros usuarios, então se eu pude ser orientado eu posso orientar para ajudar, é o que tentei fazer no primeiro comentário, te orientar com a minha experiencia, mas sua interpretação foi de que eu lhe critiquei severamente como se eu desprezasse a sua ideia...

Comment: ... mas se vc tivesse visto o quarto link que lhe enviei iria notar que eu tive a mesma ideia q vc (mas de forma diferente) a alguns anos e isso gerou um baita debate pq eu não tinha a experiencia da reação das pessoas. Segue o link: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4162/3635, nem de longe eu tentei lhe repreender ou coisa do tipo, só estou tentando lhe apresentar fatos e experiencia de muitos para talvez vc rever como aplicar a ideia, não é q não precise mudar, pq up e downs tem problemas, mas isso não resolveria com "comentários".

Comment: Tudo que vc falou foi super válido, Guilherme. Estava tudo indo super bem, até a parte da cagada da tentativa de rotular. Mas fora isso, verei seus links. Obrigado!

Comment: Não rotulei ninguém, nem você, só falei o que é experiencia, tentei lhe orientar, não vejo nada demais em querer passar experiencia, mas se sentir rotulado por algo que na verdade algo ou é presumir, ou realmente é ser o tal suposto rotulo, só que na verdade seria você quem estaria se auto-rotulando ou interpretando mal uma boa vontade de minha parte em te passar um pouco de experiencia. Sinto muito se você interpretou algo mal, não foi minha intenção, eu sempre tento ajudar no site e ajudar as pessoas a enxergarem melhor, espero que repense tudo. Um bom fim de semana.

Comment: Ok, entendi tudo muito bem. Pra vc também.

Comment: Pode começar justificando seus votos negativos. É sempre mais válido pedir por algo quando o faz sempre. Quando não o faz fica parecendo hipocrisia.

Comment: Sempre quando eu dou um upvote ou downvote, em alguma pergunta ou resposta, tenho um motivo (nessa pergunta ou resposta) para ter feito isso. Não vou ser a única pessoa aqui no Stackoverflow a justificar os meus votos. Não sou tão bonzinho quanto parece. Se um dia for uma ferramenta obrigatória para todos, como recomendei aqui nessa minha resposta, ai sim justificarei com o maior prazer. Mas eu raramente dou voto negativo aqui. Só quando acho algo muito ruim mesmo. Fique tranquilo! Tomei 4 negativações aqui e vi ninguém justificá-las.

Comment: Qual é o problema de ser um novato? Ou qual é o problema de quem tenha mais experiencia lembrar a você que está a pouco tempo aqui e ainda não viu em nem participou de todos os tipos de interações possíveis aqui na página. Eu sou novato e não tenho problema com isso e toda vez que um usuário mais experiente me faz a orientação baseado na minha inexperiência eu só tenho que agradecer porque tem um power user que se importa comigo e está disposto a compartilhar sua experiência comigo..

Comment: No final você fala 'Tomei 4 negativações aqui e vi ninguém justificá-las.' o está explicando porque ele negativou porque ele acha que você é inexperiente aqui no site e o que você acha ser uma boa ideia ele entende como uma péssima ideia pois na visão dele no inicio vai gerar muito conflito e por consequência as pessoas vão se sentir tolida do sufrágio pois vão fica com medo de votar com medo dos conflitos. Você reage brutalmente ao fato de ser levantada sua inexperiência levando para o lado pessoal corroborando que os votos negativos não devem ser obrigatoriamente identificados.

Comment: O outro justificou o downvote alegando que todos somos livres para justificar ou não os votos e sugeriu que seja um exemplo se identificando os seus votos. Mais uma vez você teve uma reação negativa soltando uma frase bizarra "...Não sou tão bonzinho quanto parece..."  alegando que não vai ser a única pessoa aqui justificando os votos.

Comment: Eu não sei se você percebeu mas a todo o momento no site as pessoas estão comentando seus votos, elas não precisam escrever "-1" elas falam na lata "olha tem aqui", "olha se não esclarecer isso aqui vou fechar sua pergunta", "olha essa resposta está baseada em documentação depreciada",... .Tem gente que tem estomago para esse tipo de discussão, eu por exemplo tenho tanto que estou analisando o seu comportamento nessa questão para justificar o meu downvote.

Comment: Agora há pessoas que são dotadas de grande visão técnica mas não possuem personalidade, energia ou disposição voltada para esse tipo de discussão. E essas pessoas merecem o anonimato em seus votos e esse anonimato deve ser respeitado.

Comment: Acho (acho) que você ainda não entendeu a minha colocação aqui e em diversos outros posts. O meu problema não é o cara ser mais experiente e eu ser menos experiente, tanto que eu canso de levantar aqui que não sou experiente mesmo e não nego isso. O problema aqui é a forma como as questões são levantadas. Essa questão de "não poder usar a questão da justificativa aqui é perigosa pois vai gerar conflito" é subjetiva (na minha opinião) e não temos como precisar isso. E se acontecer, é da 'cultura' do usuário específico.

Comment: ... Já vi "grandes mestres daqui" ficarem cobrando downvotes a outros usuários (de forma implícita). Isso se resolveria com a justificativa dos votos, na minha opinião. Isso encerra, da minha parte, o assunto em relação a "Justificativa dos votos". acho que já expliquei bastante na resposta. E por último, como levantado por você, o problema pra mim não é o cara ser mais experiente ou menos experiente, isso pouco me importa.

Comment: ...  O problema pra mim é a forma pejorativa que isso é colocado por alguns e a arrogância e prepotência que muitos utilizam para  levantar tal situação, usando isso como sinônimo de bom e ruim. Além de muita das vezes se colocarem como dono da verdade. (FIM)