# Os valores do Stack Overflow em Português

Tags: debate

Muito obrigado a [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) pela tradução.

---

Os valores de uma comunidade são os princípios e heurísticas que usamos para tomar decisões complexas e não-triviais. Eles nos dão a base para entender as regras da comunidade. Os valores são passados pelos usuários mais experientes, quando estes respondem aos mais novos sobre as suas interações no sistema.

Vamos dar uma olhada nos nossos valores juntos, discuti-los e adicioná-los à Central de Ajuda. Isso deve nos ajudar a manter a cultura da nossa comunidade no longo prazo e tornar mais eficiente a instrução de novos usuários quanto às normas da comunidade.

Há três valores que são comuns a todos os Stack Overflow internacionais:

> ## 1. Quanto mais conhecimento *bom* sobre programação em português, melhor!
>
> - **O Stack Overflow é uma biblioteca de soluções prontas** representadas por um problema (a pergunta) e as soluções (respostas), da forma mais limpa possível, com o mínimo de ruído e o máximo de foco.
> - **Perguntas e respostas são escritas uma vez e lidas milhões de vezes**. Todo o conteúdo do site é otimizado para leitura, para desenvolvedores que chegam ao site através de uma busca.
> - **Ter conteúdo útil para a comunidade é primário; como este conteúdo foi criado é secundário**. Quaisquer métodos para criar conteúdo *útil* para o site é bem-vindo, exceto quando for plágio. Entre os métodos aceitos, estão:
> - [melhores práticas, na forma de perguntas respondidas pelo próprio autor](/help/self-answer);

- [traduções bem feitas de perguntas em outros idiomas](/help/translate-from-english);

> - perguntas que são wiki da comunidade;

> E claro, [seus próprios problemas](/help/how-to-ask), para os quais acharemos juntos a resposta.
>
> ## 2. Juntos para o bem da comunidade

> - **O Stack Overflow é um esforço coletivo para criar mais conteúdo de qualidade sobre programação**. O site existe graças à colaboração de muitos usuários ativos, como você, e não por causa de [uma única e grandiosa pessoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_man_theory).
> - **Juntos criamos conteúdo útil para toda a comunidade falante de português.** Qualquer desenvolvedor falante de português que se depara com um problema pode usar as respostas do site de graça.
> - **A comunidade em si é o resultado da colaboração.** Juntos definimos o futuro do nosso site e da comunidade no meta.
>
> ## 3. Respeite os outros
>
> - **Relações dentro do grupo - como tratamos uns aos outros é a chave para o sucesso**. Nosso objetivo primário é criar e dar suporte à própria comunidade. Tudo mais virá disso.
> - **Qualquer interação com o site começa com o respeito mútuo entre colegas**, não importa as circunstâncias, reputação, conhecimento, ou o que for.
> - Na nossa comunidade, **[todos devem se sentir seguros e bem-vindos](/conduct) ao fazer perguntas ou respondê-las.**

---

Por favor compartilhe com a comunidade qual o tipo de valores que você pessoalmente vê e quais dos valores descritos acima você acha que não fazem parte desta comunidade. Que mudanças você faria no texto acima, antes de adicioná-lo na Central de Ajuda?

Mande suas opiniões, ideias e sugestões! Vamos juntos tornar nosso site ainda melhor.

---

Atualização

O novo artigo da Central de Ajuda está no ar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values

Eu peguei o máximo de feedback que pude e fiz algumas alterações. Por favor, sinta-se à vontade para editar, comentar ou fazer um ping em mim no [Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal), caso você veja algum problema ou discorde de algo. Estou mais do que feliz em discutir isso.

Comment: *Our primary goal is to create and support the community itself.* This would make sense to me only if "us" were the Community Growth team. But since these are the community values, is "us" supposed to be the community? If so, I disagree. The problem there is mixing a "values" context, where "people first" is fair enough as the first item, with the community's objectives. I don't believe the community's goal is to perpetuate itself and grow, and "everything else will follow".

Comment: [tradução] *Nosso objetivo primário é criar e dar suporte à própria comunidade*. Isso faria sentido pra mim se "nós" fosse a equipe de Community Growth da SO. Mas como isso está dentro dos valores da comunidade, "nós" estaria se referindo à comunidade? Se sim, eu discordo. O problema aí é misturar o contexto dos valores, onde "pessoas em primeiro lugar" é sensato como primeiro ponto, com os objetivos da comunidade. Eu não acho que o propósito da comunidade seja se perpetuar e crescer, e que "tudo mais virá disso".

Comment: @bfavaretto Thank you for your feedback! Please let me answer in English. I think it's a terminology issue. The comprehensive goal of the site is to create a library of answers to any programming question. It's stated in the [manifesto](/help/manifesto). Key values is a bit different thing. These are simple rules that the community uses to make internal day to day decisions. For example, "people first" means that the community values it's members, particularly we enforce mutual respect on the site. Those are not the  community's objectives. It's community's DNA.

Comment: Could you please tell me if it makes sense? Did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 20):

Isto é excelente. Uma ideia que eu acho que precisaria ficar mais clara em dois pontos é a relação entre comunidade e pessoa. Em alguns momentos a SE passa a ideia que são a mesma coisa e eu acho que são opostas.

Eu acho que se resolvermos colocar a pessoa em primeiro lugar teremos um fórum como outro qualquer. Um site de Q&A coloca a comunidade em primeiro lugar. Tudo deve ser feito para atender os interesses de todos que muitas vezes é diferente e até oposto do que um individuo deseja ou precisa. Priorizar a comunidade não é tratar mal a pessoa, mas tratar bem também não é atender os desejos específicos do indivíduo.

Vemos muito pessoas perguntando aqui como se fosse um fórum, ou seja, ela quer ser tratada como se fosse a coisa mais importante do site naquele momento e que tudo o que ele deseja tem que ser satisfeito, mesmo que isto signifique passar por cima dos valores estabelecidos pela comunidade. Isto gera fricção e precisa ficar mais claro se esta única pessoa deve receber o que quer mesmo que não seja benéfica para todos.

Não tem como agradar a todos. Se agradar a pessoa criará problemas com a comunidade que deseja agradar todos. Se priorizarmos o atendimento da necessidade da comunidade os individuos vão dizer que o SOpt não atendem suas necessidades específicas (claro que eles dirão de forma que parece que ele fez tudo certo e os outros são vilões).

É escolher o veneno a tomar e deixar claro que é esse que preferimos.

Comment: Por favor, sinta-se livre para adicionar suas recomendações ao texto na pergunta. Eu acho que estamos falando do mesmo. A primeira seção diz que o Stack Overflow é uma comunidade. E qualquer comunidade forte começa com respeito mútuo.

Comment: Respeito mútuo não significa que faremos o que alguém pede. Nós temos regras e objetivos (a segunda seção). Se alguém quebrar nossas regras com uma questão fora do tópico, nós a encerraremos e explicamos gentilmente os problemas da questão ao autor. Mas independente do que os outros façam, nós vamos manter a calma, sermos respeitosos com os outros e expressar nossa paixão pela programação. O que você acha?

Comment: Você poderia, por favor, me dizer se quer ver alguma mudança na pergunta de acordo com suas recomendações? Em caso afirmativo, sinta-se à vontade para editar a pergunta.

Comment: Creio que o que confunde um pouco é que "pessoas em primeiro lugar" dá a impressão que elas serão atendidas incondicionalmente, e não simplesmente respeitadas dentro de regras claras. Talvez seja importante deixar mais claro este ponto. Temos um problema cultural sério no Brasil que justamente é essa falta de clareza na linha que divide o que é respeito e o que é atender expectativas. Aqui infelizmente as gerações mais recentes entendem que quebra de expectativa pessoal é ofensa, num nível que está se tornando assustador (a ponto de que "regras" por si só são tomadas como ofensivas).